# How can I process each letter of text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to alert each letter of a string, but I am unsure how to do this.

So, if I have:

```js
var str = 'This is my string';
```

I would like to be able to separately alert `T`, `h`, `i`, `s`, etc.  This is just the beginning of an idea that I am working on, but I need to know how to process each letter separately.

I was thinking I might need to use the split function after testing what the length of the string is.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you were looking for this: as of ES6, there is `for(const c of str) { ... }`. More of that further below in a quite detailed but not sufficiently upvoted answer. PS: @ARJUN's link doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 641, accepted):

If the order of alerts matters, use this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  alert(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Or this:  ([see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967132/463206))

```
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   alert(str[i]);
 }
```

If the order of alerts doesn't matter, use this:

```
let i = str.length;
while (i--) {
  alert(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Or this:  ([see also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967132/463206))

```
let i = str.length;
while (i--) {
  alert(str[i]);
}
```

```js
var str = 'This is my string';

function matters() {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    alert(str.charAt(i));
  }
}

function dontmatter() {
  let i = str.length;
  while (i--) {
    alert(str.charAt(i));
  }
}
```

```html
<p>If the order of alerts matters, use <a href="#" onclick="matters()">this</a>.</p>

<p>If the order of alerts doesn't matter, use <a href="#" onclick="dontmatter()">this</a>.</p>
```

Comment: using the `[]` to get the char in a specific position isn't supported in IE < 9

Comment: as covered in the other answer, you could use str.charAt(i) in place of the []'s. for more on why you should use charAt vs [], see [string.charAt(x) or string\[x\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)

Comment: I find it hard to believe any modern JS compiler would re-calculate the length if the string hasn't been modified inside the loop. In every other language I'd happily do the length check in the test clause of the for loop, assuming the compiler knows best and would optimise it accordingly.

Comment: @Dagmar: Javascript does not use UTF-8, it uses UTF-16 (or UCS-2, depending on the browser). Every single character can be represented as either UTF-8 or UTF-16 but not have this problem. The only ones that have the problem are the ones that require four bytes in UTF-16 rather than two bytes.  is a character that requires four bytes in UTF-16. Key terms to look up for more info are "astral plane", "non-BMP", and "surrogate pair".

Comment: @hippietrail I'm a Java not Javascript dev so thanks for your reply. 

However I'd like to point out that it really depends on your container - like you said it depends on the browser (and as far as I know I can't specify the encoding I'd like to use). 

I was testing with Google App Scripts and `charAt` definitely did not work for characters like the pile of poop (which can be displayed in UTF-8 and UTF-16 as 4 bytes). https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm

Comment: @Dagmar: Java and Javascript both have UTF-16 (formerly UCS-) in common. The third major platform that uses it is Windows. Unix, MacOS, and internet protocols use UTF-8. `charAt` is left over from the UCS-2 days when there were no surrogate pairs and to address the problem a new function, `codepointAt` was added to JavaScript that handles our friendly pile of poo correctly. I believe Java also has it.

Comment: The codePointAt method gives you character codes instead of actual characters, though. Is there a method like charAt, but which correctly returns a poop emoji as a character instead of a code?

Comment: @AndrewKoster: Sometimes I too confuse two of this group of functions. Here is the whole set of them: [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt), [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), ...

Comment: @AndrewKoster: ... and [`fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)

Comment: For me the first solution was more than 50% faster when I benchmarked it on Firefox.

Comment: @RutgerWillems Faster than what?

Comment: Maybe not as good as others, but my 2 cents are => `string.split('').forEach(letter => ...);`

Comment: I personally like 2nd while solution

Answer (score 460):

It's probably more than solved. Just want to contribute with another simple solution:

```
var text = 'uololooo';

// With ES6
[...text].forEach(c => console.log(c))

// With the `of` operator
for (const c of text) {
    console.log(c)
}

// With ES5
for (var x = 0, c=''; c = text.charAt(x); x++) { 
    console.log(c); 
}

// ES5 without the for loop:
text.split('').forEach(function(c) {
    console.log(c);
});
```

Comment: the last example can simply be `[...text].forEach(console.log)`

Comment: Nope, it can't. `forEach()` passes the index and the array as second and third argument. I would rather not log that..

Comment: Note that both the spread operator (first example) and the split call (last example) will create a new array. This won't usually be a problem, but could be costly for large strings or frequent uses.

Comment: What about `for (let c of [...text]) { console.log(c) }`

Comment: With that you create a new array from the string. I don't see the benefit. `let c of text` already does the job.

Comment: What does the `...` stand for? I tried without and I see the difference but, why?

Comment: @IggyPass It's the spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: TypeScript can be funny about `[...text]` trying to treat a string as an iterator, alternatively use `text.split("")`.

Comment: Of these, only the first two will iterate through the characters of the string. The rest iterate though the UTF-16 code units. For example try `text = "\ud835\udcaf\ud835\udcae\ud835\udca9"` This string has 3 unicode characters in it, but 6 code-units.

Comment: More specifically the first two iterate through the unicode code points, not characters. Multiple unicode codepoints can make up a character.

Comment: @Flimm no need to encapsulate the console.log: `for (let c of [...str]) console.log(c)` will work

Answer (score 122):

## How to process each letter of text (with benchmarks)

<s>https://jsperf.com/str-for-in-of-foreach-map-2</s>

### for

**Classic** and by far the one with the **most performance**. You should go with this one if you are planning to use it in a performance critical algorithm, or that it requires the maximum compatibility with browser versions.

```js
var str = "Hello";
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.info(str[i]);
}
```

## for...of

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is the new **ES6** for iterator. Supported by most modern browsers. It is visually more appealing and is less prone to typing mistakes. If you are going for this one in a production application, you should be probably using a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

```
let result = '';
for (let letter of str) {
  result += letter;
}
```

## forEach

**Functional** approach. [Airbnb approved](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#iterators-and-generators). The biggest downside of doing it this way is the `split()`, that creates a new array to store each individual letter of the string.

> Why? This enforces our immutable rule. Dealing with pure functions
> that return values is easier to reason about than side effects.

```
// ES6 version.
let result = '';
str.split('').forEach(letter => {
  result += letter;
});
```

or

```
var result = '';
str.split('').forEach(function(letter) {
  result += letter;
});
```

---

The following are the ones I dislike.

### for...in

Unlike for...of, you get the letter index instead of the letter. It performs pretty badly.

```
var result = '';
for (var letterIndex in str) {
  result += str[letterIndex];
}
```

### map

Function approach, which is good. However, map isn't meant to be used for that. It should be used when needing to change the values inside an array, which is not the case.

```
// ES6 version.
var result = '';
str.split('').map(letter => {
  result += letter;
});
```

or

```
let result = '';
str.split('').map(function(letter) {
  result += letter;
});
```

Comment: On my machine the classic `for` loop was actually the second slowest, while `for...of` was the fastest (about three times as fast as `for`).

Comment: Where is the benchmark? What's the fastest solution?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Your results seem contrary to zurfyx assertion that the classic loop is fastest.

Comment: my understanding is the split method will fail on unicode or graphic symbols.

Comment: @johnywhy That was two years ago and the link is dead so I'm not sure how you expect me to defend the result I got back then. Setting up a new benchmark now agrees with zurfyx's conclusion though, with the `for` loop being slightly faster.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I don't expect you to do anything. Just a note to future readers that your results are different than the answer. I personally would like to know which results apply to browsers today 2020, altho' 2018 wasn't that long ago. Which link is dead?

Comment: @johnywhy The link at the top with all the actual tests is returning a 404 for me.

Answer (score 77):

One possible solution in pure JavaScript:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
    var char = str.charAt(i);
    alert(char);
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better with var x = 0 and var c = str.charAt(x).

Comment: Also, str.length should be stored in a variable so it doesn't have to keep being accessed.

Comment: @EliGrey Is it really that important to put length in a variable? Do you have benchmarks when this would be preferable over having fewer lines of code?

Comment: @paul_sns Interestingly, there does seem to be a *minor* difference, at least in Edge (0.7ms difference for a 10000 element array): https://jsfiddle.net/carcigenicate/v8vvjoc1/1/. Probably not a perfect test, but it's based of an average of 10000 tests.

Comment: @paul_sns Also interestingly, Chrome did the same test in around 2% of the time (~5ms vs ~0.0997ms), and both versions gave the same time, so it looks like Edge isn't optimized.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Chrome uses more processor time, so it isn't a fair test, unless you're using an OS with perfect, static throttling. And such an OS isn't very useful for multitasking, as a program that grabs loads of PIDs will get lots of time (something Chrome *also* does!).

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I think your test is mostly measuring the performance of Array.push instead of Array.length.

Comment: for (var x = 0, c=''; c = "".charAt(x); x++) { 
    console.log(c); 
}

Comment: "One possible solution in pure javascript". Oh I'm sure there's a jQuery plugin to do this easily, why bother looping??

Answer (score 62):

Most if not all of the answers here are wrong because they will break whenever there is a character in the string [outside the Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567249/what-are-the-most-common-non-bmp-unicode-characters-in-actual-use). That means **all Emoji will be broken**.

JavaScript uses [UTF-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16)[16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Unicode for all strings. In UTF-16, characters beyond the BMP are made out of two parts, called a "[Surrogate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/dd374069(v=vs.85).aspx) [Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java)" and most of the answers here will process each part of such pairs individually instead of as a single character.

One way in modern JavaScript since at least 2016 is to use the new [String iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator). Here's the example (almost) straight out of MDN:

```js
var string = 'A\uD835\uDC68B\uD835\uDC69C\uD835\uDC6A';

for (var v of string) {
  alert(v);
}
// "A"
// "\uD835\uDC68"
// "B"
// "\uD835\uDC69"
// "C"
// "\uD835\uDC6A"
```

Comment: For a modern solution to splitting a string into characters while taking into account surrogate pairs, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42596897/527702

Answer (score 19):

You can try this

```
var arrValues = 'This is my string'.split('');
// Loop over each value in the array.
$.each(arrValues, function (intIndex, objValue) {
    alert(objValue);
})
```

Comment: Still is an option, but not performant. Don't put jQuery everywhere.

Comment: Don't use any libraries, unless you really need it.

Answer (score 16):

New JS allows this:

```
const str = 'This is my string';
Array.from(str).forEach(alert);
```

Comment: Best answer! I intuitively tried it and it worked, wanted to post it, then discovered that I'm too late )

Answer (score 15):

If you want to do a transformation on the text on a character level, and get the transformed text back at the end, you would do something like this:

```
var value = "alma";
var new_value = [...value].map((x) => x+"E").join("")
```

So the steps:

- [Split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717402) the string into an array (list) of characters
- Map each character via a functor
- Join the resulting array of chars together into the resulting string

NOTE: If you need performance, there are probably better, more optimized solutions for this. I posted this one as a clean codestyle approach.

Comment: This is one of the solution, but it is not an optimized solution.

Answer (score 10):

One more solution...

```
var strg= 'This is my string';
for(indx in strg){
  alert(strg[indx]);
}
```

Comment: If you only want the char and not the index, it would be faster to use a `for..of` loop `for (let ch of t) { alert(ch) }`

Answer (score 10):

It is better to use the for...of statement, if the string contains unicode characters, because of the different byte size.

```
for(var c of "tree 木") { console.log(c); }
//"A".length === 3
```

Answer (score 10):

short answer: `Array.from(string)` will give you what you probably want and then you can iterate on it or whatever since it's just an array.

ok let's try it with this string: `abc|⚫️\n⚪️|‍‍‍`.

codepoints are:

```
97
98
99
124
9899, 65039
10
9898, 65039
124
128104, 8205, 128105, 8205, 128103, 8205, 128103
```

so some characters have one codepoint (byte) and some have two or more, and a newline added for extra testing.

so after testing there are two ways:

- byte per byte (codepoint per codepoint)
- character groups (but not the whole family emoji)

```js
string = "abc|⚫️\n⚪️|‍‍‍"

console.log({ 'string': string }) // abc|⚫️\n⚪️|‍‍‍
console.log({ 'string.length': string.length }) // 21

for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i += 1) {
  console.log({ 'string[i]': string[i] }) // byte per byte
  console.log({ 'string.charAt(i)': string.charAt(i) }) // byte per byte
}

for (let char of string) {
  console.log({ 'for char of string': char }) // character groups
}

for (let char in string) {
  console.log({ 'for char in string': char }) // index of byte per byte
}

string.replace(/./g, (char) => {
  console.log({ 'string.replace(/./g, ...)': char }) // byte per byte
});

string.replace(/[\S\s]/g, (char) => {
  console.log({ 'string.replace(/[\S\s]/g, ...)': char }) // byte per byte
});

[...string].forEach((char) => {
  console.log({ "[...string].forEach": char }) // character groups
})

string.split('').forEach((char) => {
  console.log({ "string.split('').forEach": char }) // byte per byte
})

Array.from(string).forEach((char) => {
  console.log({ "Array.from(string).forEach": char }) // character groups
})

Array.prototype.map.call(string, (char) => {
  console.log({ "Array.prototype.map.call(string, ...)": char }) // byte per byte
})

var regexp = /(?:[\0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g

string.replace(regexp, (char) => {
  console.log({ 'str.replace(regexp, ...)': char }) // character groups
});
```

Answer (score 9):

When I need to write short code or a one-liner, I use this "hack":

```
'Hello World'.replace(/./g, function (char) {
    alert(char);
    return char; // this is optional 
});
```

This won't count newlines so that can be a good thing or a bad thing. If you which to include newlines, replace: `/./` with `/[\S\s]/`. The other one-liners you may see probably use `.split()` which [has many problems](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

Comment: best answer. Takes into account problems with unicode and also can be used with functional constructs with .map() etc.

Comment: Only thing I don't like about this one is when I want access to the [extra params passed to the `forEach` call's function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters) vs the [params sent in `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). If I know I'm ASCIIing, I think I still have some use cases for `split`. Great answer, though!

Comment: This answer has the bonus with preselecting the values you would check against anyway

Comment: I thought this wouldn't take into account the Unicode problems unless it had the `u` flag along with the `g` flag? OK just tested and I was right.

Answer (score 9):

You can now use *in* keyword.

```js
    var s = 'Alien';
    for (var c in s) alert(s[c]);
```

Comment: Using in is bad practice and horrible when unfiltered I strongly advise against this

Comment: @Downgoat why? What's bad about it? I mean if I'm in a situation where I know that 'in' is supported by my Javascript engine, and that my code won't find its way into another engine...why not use that?

Comment: @TKoL See [this](https://thecodebarbarian.com/for-vs-for-each-vs-for-in-vs-for-of-in-javascript#non-numeric-properties).

Comment: @Alan `in` is a legitimate part of the language. Use things appropriately. Your article cautions that `in` interprets alpha keys same as numeric keys. So? Maybe that's what you want. It could also be said that other methods *incorrectly* ignore alpha keys. Imo, `of` has correct behavior. In JS arrays, elements without alpha keys still have keys: numeric ones. In my console, JS "correctly" treats the alpha key same as the numeric keys:
`>const arr = ['a', 'b']
>arr.test = 'hello'
>arr
0: "a"
1: "b"
test: "hello"
length: 2`

Comment: There is nothing wrong about the usage of `in` if you know what data formats you have and in this case we know exactly that we have a string as an array. @johnywhy I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 8):

You can now iterate over individual Unicode code points contained in a String by using `String.prototype[@@iterator]`, which returns a value of well known Symbol type `Symbol.iterator` - the default iterator for array-like Objects (`String` in this case).

Example code:

```js
const str = 'The quick red  jumped over the lazy ! 太棒了！';

let iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]();
let theChar = iterator.next();

while(!theChar.done) {
  console.log(theChar.value);
  theChar = iterator.next();
}

// logs every unicode character as expected into the console.
```

This works with Unicode characters such as emoji or non-roman characters that would trip up legacy constructs.

Reference: [MDN Link to String.prototype@@iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator).

Comment: Note that you can do this in a shorter manner with a `for ... of` loop as well over the string - that is syntax sugar for accessing the iterator.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply iterate it as in an array:

```js
var txt = "Hello";
for(var i in txt){
    console.log(txt[i]);
}
```

Comment: and nowadays even `for (var i of txt) { console.log(i) }`

Answer (score 7):

In ES6 / ES2015, you can iterate over an string with `iterators`,as you can see in

[Symbol.iterator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Symbol/iterator)

```js
var str = 'Hello';
var it = str[Symbol.iterator]();

for (let v of it) {
  console.log(v)
 }
 
//  "H"
//  "e"
//  "l"
//  "l"
//  "o"
```

It is a **declarative style**. What is the *advantage*? You do not have to concern about how to access each element of the string.

Answer (score 6):

```js
// There are multiple ways but I find this easiest.

let str = 'This is my string';
for(let character of str) 
  console.log(character)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get an array of the individual characters like so

```
var test = "test string",
    characters = test.split('');
```

and then loop using regular Javascript, or else you can iterate over the string's characters using jQuery by

```
var test = "test string";

$(test.split('')).each(function (index,character) {
    alert(character);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can convert this string into an array of chars using `split()`, then iterate through it.

```js
const str = "javascript";
const strArray = str.split('');

strArray.map(s => console.log(s));
```

Comment: apparently this fails with unicode characters and graphic symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In today's JavaScript you can

`Array.prototype.map.call('This is my string', (c) => c+c)`

Obviously, c+c represents whatever you want to do with c.

This returns

`["TT", "hh", "ii", "ss", "  ", "ii", "ss", "  ", 
  "mm", "yy", "  ", "ss", "tt", "rr", "ii", "nn", "gg"]`

Comment: Possibly: `[...'This is my string'].map((c)=>c+c)`

Answer (score 0):

This should **work in older browsers** and with UTF-16 characters like .

This should be the most compatible solution. However, it is less performant than a `for` loop would be.

I generated the regular expression using [regexpu](https://mothereff.in/regexpu)

```js
var str = 'My String  ';
var regEx = /(?:[\0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g


str.replace(regEx, function (char) {
    console.log(char)
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "less perfomant"? I think you mean "slower" as it is more conformant to the requirement and it performs well.

Answer (score -1):

You can [access single characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) with `str.charAt(index)` or `str[index]`. But the latter way is not part of ECMAScript so you better go with the former one.

Comment: I'd stay away from that.  Unfortunately that doesn't work in all versions of IE.  Trust me.  I learned it the hard way.

Comment: It is part of ECMAScript, but only in newly-released 5th edition, not 3rd.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to animate each character you might need to wrap it in span element;

```
var $demoText = $("#demo-text");
$demoText.html( $demoText.html().replace(/./g, "<span>$&amp;</span>").replace(/\s/g, " "));
```

I think this is the best way to do it, then process the spans. ( for example with TweenMax)

TweenMax.staggerFromTo( $demoText.find("span"), 0.2, {autoAlpha:0}, {autoAlpha:1}, 0.1 );

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
    function myFunction() {
    var text =(document.getElementById("htext").value); 
    var meow = " <p> <,> </p>";
    var i;


    for (i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {

        text+=text[i] ;



    }

    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;

}
</script>
<p>Enter your text: <input type="text" id="htext"/>

    <button onclick="myFunction();">click on me</button>
</p>
```