# Not sure why IDLE automatically added *-* coding: utf-8 -*- to my script

Tags: python, encoding, python-idle

Initially I installed version 3.4 of Python and then I added version 2.7 as a video course instructor was using it as well.

After I opened IDLE and wrote some code, pressed F5 a meessage popped up. I accepted the message and from then on this line was added in IDLE on the top of my file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I tried to read it through wikipedia but it is too long. Could you be able to explain me if that is a consequence of having two versions of the python installed in my computer and in layperson words; what is utf-8?

Comment: Have a look at [What is unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103/1401034). On your multiple pythons installed it means exactly that, you can run your program with either 2.7 or 3.4. There are [syntax differences](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) between the two versions

Comment: Stop with the down vote floods please as this is a legitimate (albeit badly worded) question.

Comment: I assume that you were running 2.7 and that you typed some non-ascii characters. The same would have happened without installing 3.4 first.  For 2.7, if you look at Options - > Idle Preverences -> General (tab), you will see your choices for Default Source Encoding.  If utf-8 is checked because of your choice in response to the prompt, I would leave it unless you really know that your should change it.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy yes. UTF-8 is checked. I will leave. Honestly, right  now I do not know why and when I should change that option. This is my 5th day into programming in python and I still need to learn a lot of material.

Comment: The only reasons I can think of would be if an instructor required you to submit programs with a different encoding or if you wanted to real your .py files with software that absolutely refused to read utf-8.  I hope neither of these are ever true.

Comment: Neither of these are true. Initially I started to learn to code with 3.4. 
Yesterday I started with MOOC on python programming for beginners. The instructor is using 2.7. so I wanted to code in 2.7. as well and this is why I installed this version as well. 
However, after I started I experienced this utf-8 event. After the conversation with u guys I have more clear picture about what utf-8 and encoding is, but for non native english and non tech starting to learn to code is not a piece of cake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, when you write some code and create some strings, for example:

```
x = 'Hello'
print(x)
```

Python needs to know what encoding to use to read the strings. Its not a problem if you are only using English (as this is the default), but if you write something like this:

```
x = 'Aleksandar Gavrič'
print 'My name is %s' % x
```

Python does not know what `č` is (since for some very old reasons it only understands English by default). To tell it how to read `č` correctly, you need to tell it what *encoding* the file is using.

IDLE is smart enough to detect when you are typing non-English characters in strings and will prompt and suggest you to add a special comment to the top of the file to help Python read your code - that's what you clicked on and the result was that line was added to the top.

For more details, you can read the [Python documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) which describes what that line is, why its needed etc.

For more on what is encoding and utf-8, take a few minutes and have a read through [this excellent article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) which explains this concept and history behind it.

Comment: I believe the prompting should only happen in 2.x.  In 3.x, Idle writes utf-8 by default and python reads utf-8 by default.