# How to convert a Chinese string to english for windows phone store apps[Javascript]

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, nfc

i am creating a nfc functionality for app. When sending nfc message from android to windows phone 8.1, the message comes as chinese. How can i convert this into english. Is there any utf like methods for for windows phone 8.1 javascript.

Comment: you have Chinese text that you need translated to English? That has nothing to do with encoding (utf), so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: OK I just want to translate the Chinese text to english.

Comment: Was the original message English? I think you have an encoding problem, not a translation problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into third party services to do Chinese to English translation. There is nothing built in to the Operating System or runtime that can do that.

[UTF is a character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16) only and had no relation to the actual content or meaning of encoded characters.

Comment: Can I use Google translate api

Comment: I don't know. Have you looked at it? I'm not sure what license it has and the cost. Bing also has one.