# Something wrong with encoding while writing

Tags: php, utf-8, fwrite

I'm trying to write some (generated) data to an file with this piece of code:

```
define("LANG_DIR", "/var/www/html/app/lang/");
define("TAB", "\t");
define("NL", "\n");
define('FILE_START', '<?php' . NL . NL . "return array(" . NL);
define('FILE_END', NL . ');');

// Some parsing here    

foreach ($fileContent as $fileName => $value) {
    $fileString = FILE_START;

    foreach ($value as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
        $fileString .= TAB . "'" . $arrayKey . "'" . TAB . TAB . "=>" . TAB . TAB .  "'" . $arrayValue . "'," . NL;
    }

    $fileString .= FILE_END;

    $filePath = LANG_DIR . $desLang . "/" . $fileName . ".php";
    $filePath = strval(str_replace("\0", "", $filePath));

    $handle = fopen($filePath, "w+b");
    fwrite($handle, $fileString); // "\xEF\xBB\xBF" .
    fclose($handle);

    echo $filePath . "<br />";
    echo '<br /><textarea rows="10" cols="100"> ' . $fileString . '</textarea><br />';
}
```

This will result in files looking like this:

```
3c3f 7068 700a 0a72 6574 7572 6e20 6172
7261 7928 0a09 2700 6900 6e00 6100 6300
7400 6900 7600 6500 2709 093d 3e09 0927
0049 006e 0061 006b 0074 0069 0076 0065
0020 0047 0061 0062 0065 006c 0073 0074
0061 0070 006c 0065 0072 0027 2c0a 0927
006e 0069 0065 0075 0077 0027 0909 3d3e
0909 2700 4e00 6500 7500 6500 7200 2000
4700 6100 6200 6500 6c00 7300 7400 6100
7000 6c00 6500 7200 272c 0a09 2700 6900
6400 2709 093d 3e09 0927 0049 0044 0027
2c0a 0927 006e 0061 006d 0065 0027 0909
3d3e 0909 2700 4e00 6100 6d00 6500 2000
4700 6100 6200 6500 6c00 7300 7400 6100
7000 6c00 6500 7200 272c 0a09 2700 7300
7400 6100 7400 7500 7300 2709 093d 3e09
0927 0053 0074 0061 0074 0075 0073 0027
2c0a 0927 0069 0070 0027 0909 3d3e 0909
2700 4900 5000 2000 4e00 7500 6d00 6d00
6500 7200 272c 0a09 2700 6100 6300 7400
6900 6f00 6e00 2709 093d 3e09 0927 0041
006b 0074 0069 006f 006e 0065 006e 0027
2c0a 0927 0061 0063 0074 0069 0076 0065
0027 0909 3d3e 0909 2700 4100 6b00 7400
6900 7600 272c 0a09 2700 6200 7500 7400
7400 6f00 6e00 5f00 7400 6900 7400 6c00
6500 5f00 6e00 6500 7700 2709 093d 3e09
0927 0045 0069 006e 0065 006e 0020 006e
0065 0075 0065 006e 0020 0047 0061 0062
0065 006c 0073 0074 0061 0070 006c 0065
0072 0020 0068 0069 006e 007a 0075 0066
00fc 0067 0065 006e 0027 2c0a 0927 0062
0075 0074 0074 006f 006e 005f 0074 0069
0074 006c 0065 005f 0065 0064 0069 0074
0027 0909 3d3e 0909 2700 4400 6900 6500
7300 6500 6e00 2000 4700 6100 6200 6500
6c00 7300 7400 6100 7000 6c00 6500 7200
2000 6200 6500 6100 7200 6200 6500 6900
7400 6500 6e00 272c 0a0a 293b
```

If I use the so-called UTF-8 BOM like this:

```
fwrite($handle, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $fileString);
```

I get this writen to the file:

[image]

But when I echo it to an `textarea`, I get the following output:

```
return array(
    'inactive'      =>      'Inaktive Gabelstapler',
    'nieuw'     =>      'Neuer Gabelstapler',
    'id'        =>      'ID',
    'name'      =>      'Name Gabelstapler',
    'status'        =>      'Status',
    'ip'        =>      'IP Nummer',
    'action'        =>      'Aktionen',
    'active'        =>      'Aktiv',
    'button_title_new'      =>      'Einen neuen Gabelstapler hinzufügen',
    'button_title_edit'     =>      'Diesen Gabelstapler bearbeiten',

);
```

So my question is very simple... What is happening? I heard somebody say something about utf-8 and ISO stuff, but I don't know anything about that....

**Edit**
As commented by @axiac, I've encoded the define's now in this way:

```
$fileString = convertEnc(FILE_START);

foreach ($value as $arrayKey => $arrayValue) {
    $fileString .= convertEnc(TAB) . "'" . $arrayKey . "'" . convertEnc(TAB) . convertEnc(TAB) . "=>" . convertEnc(TAB) . convertEnc(TAB) .  "'" . $arrayValue . "'," . convertEnc(NL);
}

$fileString .= convertEnc(FILE_END);
```

// Some more code...

```
function convertEnc($input){
    return mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-16');
}
```

This will result in:

[image]

Which is better (you can read some text now), but still isn't what I'm expecting...

Comment: Besides the encoding problem (your code produces a mix of 8-bit and 16-bit encoded characters that is not UTF-8), you have reinvented the wheel. Take a look at the PHP function [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Comment: @axiac About the var-export. Thank you for linking that function. Didn't knew of it. But do you know how i could fix the 8 and 16 bit encoded problem?

Comment: The 8-bit encoded characters are generated by your PHP code (the defines `TAB`, `NL` a.s.o). The 16-bit encoded characters come from the values stored in variable `$fileContent`. You didn't show how you put data in it. It looks like you load the text from a little-endian UTF-16 encoded file (generated on Windows?). The PHP functions defined by the [`mb_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) extension can be used to detect the encoding of a string and convert it to a different encoding.

Comment: @axiac I import it from an `utf-8` `.csv` file. So you're basically stating that I i convert the define's to utf-8, it will be fine? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Take a look at your encoded data. There is an `ü` in `hinzufügen`. In `UTF-8`, [`ü`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9C) is encoded using two bytes: `C3 BC`, all the other characters from your output are encoded using a single byte. In your hex dump `ü` is encoded as `FC 00`. This is not `UTF-8` but [`UTF-16LE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Byte_order_encoding_schemes). Also, the other characters you have in `$fileContent` are encoded using 2 bytes (`'a'` is `61 00`, `'b'` is `62 00` a.s.o). The characters you put around them are encoded as 1-byte (`3c` is `<`, `3f` is `?` a.s.o).

Comment: @axiac You sir, saved my day. I've fixed it now. After converting the define's to `UTF-16LE`, I get the desired outputs. If you could make an nice answer of the point about encoding, I could accept it.

Comment: @axiac Is that possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82077/discussion-between-axiac-and-mathlight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the question's comments (and further in the chat), I think the data in `$fileContent` has the wrong encoding; it seems to be `UTF-16` while `UTF-8` is more useful and easier to manipulate.

I recommend you to try to fix the encoding of the data from `$fileContent` at the source (when the files are generated).

If this is not possible, this is how I would write the code:

```
// Create the converting function
// It assumes the input string is encoded as UTF-16
// and converts the encoding to UTF-8
$fnFixEncoding = function ($input) {
    return mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
};

// Process all the files
foreach ($fileContent as $fileName => $value) {
    // Fix the encoding of the keys and values of $value individually
    // then re-compose the array
    $value = array_combine(
        array_map($fnFixEncoding, array_keys($value)),
        array_map($fnFixEncoding, array_values($value))
    );

    // Generate the PHP code
    $text = '<?php return '.var_export($value, TRUE).';';

    // Generate the file path
    $filePath = LANG_DIR.$desLang.'/'.$fileName.'.php';
    // If $fileName is also encoded as UTF-16 you need to change its encoding too
    // Use $fnFixEncoding($fileName) instead of $fileName in the line above

    // Write the code in the file
    file_put_contents($filePath, $text);
}

// That's all!
```

#### Remarks

If the encoding of the input strings is not known or not always the same then the encoding function must have a more elaborate implementation that can use [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) to find the encoding of the input string and pass it as the third argument to [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php):

```
$fnFixEncoding = function ($input) {
    // The third argument is a list of possible encodings used by $input
    $enc = mb_detect_encoding($input, ['UTF-16', 'UTF-8', 'ISO8859-1']);
    return mb_convert_encoding($input, 'UTF-8', $enc);
};
```

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16) some more information about encodings