# Getting the correct Collator setting in ICU

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

The requirement is to be able to do case insensitive operations on both ASCII and Unicode strings. Each input string is encoded using `UTF-16LE` and stored as a `std::basic_string<u_int16_t>` data type. The majority of suggestions pointed at ICU, so I took a stab at it.

I wrote a sample code to try out a few sample inputs:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "unicode/coll.h"

using namespace icu;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UErrorCode success = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    Collator *collator = Collator::createInstance("UTF-16LE", success);
    collator->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);

    if (collator->compare("dinç", "DINÇ") == 0) {
        cout << "Strings are equal" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Strings are unequal" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The strings in question have turkish characters. From what I read, the string comparison should fail since `'i'` and `'I'` are different in character set regardless of whether they're both upper or lower case. But they are deemed equal.

A couple questions:

1. Should the strings be UTF-16 encoded prior to feeding them to ICU? Would that solve the problem?
2. In general, which collator settings are ideal to support case insensitive operations on UTF-16 encoded strings? I read that when strength is set to PRIMARY and SECONDARY, it results in case insensitive comparison. In addition to this, is there any thing else that I might be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In addition to this, is there any thing else that I might be missing?

YES! Your code is missing the Turkish.

The Unicode casing rules are kinda simple, until you get Turkish in there†. [Turkish `I`s are messy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I). The uppercase form of `i` is `İ`, not `I`, and the lowercase form of `I`, is `ı`, not `i`; and the pair `i`/`İ` denotes a different letter from the pair `ı`/`I`.

This means that there are two different sets of rules for case-insensitive comparison: one where `i` is equal to `I` (most locales), and one where it is different (for Turkish and Azerbaijani locales).

In order to get the Turkish locale semantics with ICU you need to [create a collator with a specific locale](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1Collator.html#af7aa04c72be7c47935cc5c6308c0677c), in this case the tr_TR locale.

---

† not only Turkish. There are four languages with weird casing rules; from least messy to hellish: Turkish and Azeri, Lithuanian, Greek.

Comment: Thanks! Barring the four languages you mentioned, would a collator with  UTF-16 as locale be able to handle case insensitive operations for most other languages?

Comment: Also this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16) says that UTF-16 size is variable and can go up to 4 bytes. If so, the storage needed for the strings needs to change to `std::basic_string<u_int32_t>` or the equivalent, correct?

Comment: @Maddy it would be able to do equality comparisons, but ordering (aka collation) varies a lot from language to language, so no. Also, no don't change your strings. UTF-16 uses 16-bit units.