# How can I encode a unicode text file into utf-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Just like I said, I wanto to know how to change a unicode txt file into a UTF-8 file. Could you help me?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. In brief, "unicode" is a standard which standardises a wide range of related things relating to representing test on computers (including, but not limited to, encoding, sorting, conversion, etc). UTF-8 is a character encoding (that is, it specifies how bytes map to glyphs). See: [What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2241348/660921).

Comment: As asked, this is not a programing question, and so is off-topic for StackOverflow. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in a text editor like Notepad, and select the option Save-As. Then from the encoding drop down menu, choose UTF-8, and click Save. It's as simple as that.

[image: Picture: Steps to save as UTF-8]