# How to correct the encoding of the data scraped with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a python scraper using beautifulsoup. I successfully extracted most of the data, but I am facing now an encoding problem in the price extraction.

Here is my example:

The actual text is 1599€99

The scrapped text is:

```
>>>prdt.find("span",{"class":"price"}).text
u'1599\u20ac99'
```

"\u20ac" is supposed to be the '€' symbol using UTF-8 encoding however:

```
>>>prdt.find("span",{"class":"price"}).text.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
'1599\xe2\x82\xac99'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's representation of a unicode string. You may see its content by simply printing it.

```
>>> u1= u'1599\u20ac99'

>>> print u1
# prints 1599€99

>>> u2 = u'1599€99'

>>> u2
# prints u'1599\u20ac99'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script works well:

```
>>> prdt.find("span",{"class":"price"}).text
u'1599\u20ac99'
```

The return value is a valid **unicode** string. The character u"\u20ac" is the [EURO SIGN](http://unicode-table.com/en/20AC/).

If you encode this character using 'utf8' encoding you get a **bytes** string.

```
>>> u'\u20ac'.encode('utf8')
b'\xe2\x82\xac'
```

This is the same code point encoded in UTF-8: E2 82 AC.

See also this answer to [What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103/1513933).