# What is <meta charset="UTF-8">?

Tags: html

What is meta charset="UTF-8" system of numbers, letters, or signals used to represent something in a shorter or more convenient form: The message was written in code.

Comment: I understand that English is not your mother tongue but your question lacks context and doesn't make any sense. What are you doing? Where did you copy that text from?

Comment: Sorry sir in the body i have to write something but the bots didn't give me the permission for my sentences that's why i done that.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a variable width character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid code points in Unicode using one to four 8-bit bytes. The encoding is defined by the Unicode standard, and was originally designed by Ken Thompson and Rob Pike
UTF-8 is backwards compatible with ASCII. UTF-8 is the preferred encoding for e-mail and web pages
In theory, any character encoding can be used, but no browser understands all of them. The more widely a character encoding is used, the better the chance that a browser will understand it.
The Unicode code point for "€" is U+20AC.

Comment: In a simple way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16