# Web Crawler Array error: "list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, index-error

I am not too strong in Python but I am building a site for a guild I am a part of in a game, and I am using a crawler to pull some of our members data off of another site (yes I did receive permission to do so). I am using beautiful soup 4 with python 3.7. I am receiving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/UsersLaptop/Desktop/swgohScraper.py", line 21, in <module>
    temp = members[count]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**My Code is Here:**

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# variables
count = 1

# lists to store data
names = []
gp = []
arenaRank = []

url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/'
response = get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(soup)

members = soup.find_all('tr')
members.sort()

for users in members:
    temp = members[count]
    name = temp.td.a.strong.text
    names.append(name)
    count += 1

print(names)
```

I am guessing I am receiving this error due to the fact that members has 50 members in it but the 50th is null, and I would need to stop the array from appending if the data was null however when I tried putting an if loop under my for loop such as:

```
if users.find('tr') is not None:
```

it does not fix the issue. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain how to solve this issue, and why the solution works. Thank you in advance!

Comment: PS even after looking at similarly asked questions I cannot seem to figure this out and it is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Indices start from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the job of what you trying to get from the code i.e trying to get the names as could be infered from the code

```
from requests import get

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# variables
count = 1

# lists to store data
names = []
gp = []
arenaRank = []

url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/'
response = get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for users in soup.findAll('strong'):
    if users.text.strip().encode("utf-8")!= '':
        names.append(users.text.strip().encode("utf-8"))



print(names)
```

Comment: You are the closest to solving my issue, and the only one who hasn't given code that throws an error, so thank you! This is printing something like this: [u'Note', u'', u'GP'] which I am confused about because shouldn't strip be removing the u and the ' '?

Comment: That`s just the encoding part.I have edited the answer for the same!

Comment: added the code for ignoring any empty data ' ' too.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you explain why you need the .encode part? You are the only one who understood my question and were able to solve it. I really am having trouble understanding what the .encode("utf-8") does though.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16 and just one friendly advice,before asking a question read thoroughly about.I know learning new thing can be challenging but you will learn about it gradually,just try/read every nook and corner about it.Its a good practice will definetly help you grow! Happy coding and learning!

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I am only in college so I'm doing my best. I really love coding and I know I have a TON to learn. It's hard because I feel like I am pushing myself hard and stepping into topics that may be a bit advanced for me at the time but I dont want to slow down. All of this is simply for fun and practice. I really appreciate you being nice and bearing with me :)

Comment: You will figure things out! Just stay calm , do what you love and always be curious! Don`t be disheartened by failures. Best Wishes!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `for in` loop, you don't need the count variable.

```
for users in members:
    name = users.td.a.strong.text
    names.append(name)
```

Comment: Brings up "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'" when this happens. I realized I didn't need the count variable but I seemed to have it working in a better state with it.

Answer (score 0):

change `count=0` at first,because members index from 0

Comment: I realize index does not start at 0, but the beginning of the list is not an item I need so I am skipping it. This does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
# lists to store data
names = []
gp = []
arenaRank = []

url = 'https://swgoh.gg/g/21284/gid-1-800-druidia/'
response = get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(soup)

members = soup.find_all('tr')
members.sort()

for users in members:
    name = users.td.a.strong.text
    names.append(name)


print(names)
```

You can change `count` to 0 because python indexing starts from 0, but best is still to directly do it from the iterator `users`

Comment: This code does not work. I realize that python indexing starts at 0. I also originally wrote this code but this code brings up an error saying "NoneType" object has no attribute a. It is clearly grabbing something that has no anchor tag, so I would have to leave out one of the 50 elements but I am not sure how. I believe there are 49 members out of a possible 50 so I need the 49 members and then for it to fill in one empty spot with just an empty string.