# Is there any way for tkinter Entry widgets to accepted polish letters?

Tags: python, tkinter

Lets say this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

entry = Entry(window)
entry.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

When user types polish letters he then gets weird symbols such a ¹œæ. How to fix that? When I use `e.insert(END, "ąść")` I see normal polish letters.

Answer (score -1):

The issue might have occurred because the encoding is set to UTF-8 and not UTF-16. (Refer to the thread [What is Unicode, UTF-8, UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-is-unicode-utf-8-utf-16))

**Quick Fix:** Use `u'required_string'` instead of `'required_string'`.

**Rectified Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

entry = Entry(window)
entry.pack()
entry.insert(END, u"ąść")
window.mainloop()
```

**Output:**

[image: Output showing the required polish letters being displayed]

Comment: I don't think you understood the question — it's about the _user_ typing character into an on-screen `Entry` widget, not inserting them via the `insert()` method.

Comment: Also, in Python 3, which this question is definitely using (the module is named `Tkinter` on Python 2), there is *zero* difference between `u"ąść"` and `"ąść"`; the `u` prefix switched from `str` (bytes-like) to `unicode` on Py2, but on Py3, `str` is roughly equivalent to Py2 `unicode`; they both handle Unicode text.