# Atomic Kotlin, Data Types: Excercise 3

Tags: kotlin

thanks for looking and possibly responding

```
val c1 = 'a' + 1
val c2 = 'a' + 25
val c3 = 'E' - 2

// 'a' + 1
val c1 = 'b'

// 'a' + 25
val c2 = ??

// 'E' - 2
val c3 = 'C'
```

complete noob, why does val c2 = z

I cant understand how 86 translates to 'z'. The unicode table does not give a character that represents 86.

Comment: Why do you think that `c2` is `88`?

Comment: thanks for responding, im learning as i go, if a small case a is U+0061 then 61 + 25 = 86, WHOOPS, not 88, i guess i'll be editing my question first

Comment: You're mixing hexadecimal and decimal. `'a'` is 61 hex, i.e. 97 decimal. So it's 97 +25 == 122 (7A hex).

Comment: The letter is 'z' is 25 points ahead of the letter 'a'. Does this give you any hint?

Comment: okay so firstly, thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys. Sounds like I have a to add a few more topics to my reading list. All of your answers are very helpful but assume that i have the prerequisite knowledge, which i currently don't. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Kotlin [Char](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/) is, basically, just a regular number that represents a Unicode character ([What are Unicode, UTF-8, and UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241348/4161471)). Each number is assigned to a character, which we can look up in [a unicode table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin). In this we can see that the letter `a` has a decimal representation of `97`.

[image: screenshot of unicode table, highlighting]

You could also get the decimal value using [Char.code](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/code.html)

```kotlin
fun main() {
  println('a'.code)
}
```

```
97
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/ns_V1PJnN)

Therefore, in decimal, `97 + 25 = 122`.

Looking up 122 in the Unicode table reveals that this is the decimal representation of `z`. You can again use `Char.code` to get the decimal representation.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  println(('a' + 25).code)
  println('a' + 25)
}
```

```
122
z
```

[*Run in Kotlin Playground*](https://pl.kotl.in/GfZhCT-LH)