# Swift `String.Encoding`: `.unicode` vs `.utf16`

Tags: swift, unicode, utf-16, nsstringencoding

`String.Encoding` struct features several unicode related implementations:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding

- `utf8`
- `utf16` and its modifications
- `utf32` and its modifications
- and suddenly, `unicode`

What is this `unicode` case, what's it for? Is this just an alias to some particular encoding like `utf16`? Or maybe, this is just some umbrella value which means "any unicode encoding" and in some contexts it will evaluate to `utf8`, and in some - to `utf16`?

Comment: Maybe some info there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-are-unicode-utf-8-and-utf-16 ?

Comment: @Larme Yes, as SO advises, I have extensively looked through the recommended topics and this was one of them. This topic is not related to my question. I know the  difference between Unicode and its implementations perfectly well. My question only regards Apple's API. `String.Encoding` implies me picking a particular implementation and I am wondering, what does a classification term do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Sources/Foundation/StringEncodings.swift) for swift-corelibs-foundation, `utf16` is the same as `unicode`:

> ```
> public static let utf16 = Encoding.unicode
> ```

This makes sense, as the `NSStringEncoding` (which presumably is what the cases of `String.Encoding` are based on) values are also like this. The docs for [`NSUTF16StringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1497293-string_encodings/nsutf16stringencoding?language=objc) says it is an alias of `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`.

Comment: Oh wow, there is literally one more string of information in the Objective-C docs that can't be found in Swift docs, and it answers my questions... I thought, the docs were supposed to be one-to-one same...

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg `NSString` and `String` are 2 completely independent types. `String` is a native Swift type that's part of the Swift standard library and is written in Swift. `NSString` on the other hand is an Obj-C type that's part of (NS)Foundation. So the docs in this case cannot be the same because they're about different types. The docs are only the same when you're viewing the docs for a type that's available as is to both Swift and Obj-C.

Comment: I'd say it *doesn't* make sense because there is a type called [`UnicodeScalarView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/unicodescalarview) and it would make sense if `Encoding.unicode` corresponded to that type. Can't argue with the code though.

Comment: @JeremyP Unicode scalars isn’t an encoding though. It is the job of an encoding to convert Unicode scalars to bytes.

Comment: @Sweeper it is an encoding. It converts a Unicode string into something called "unicode scalars" which are 21 bit numbers according to the docs (contained within a `UInt32`). An encoding doesn't have to convert to bytes - UTF-16 and UTF-32 are encodings and they convert to `UInt16` and `UInt32` respectively.