# Casting each char from span vs MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>

Tags: c#, utf-8, marshalling

When debugging an operation with UTF8 strings, sometimes I want to see the string representation from a given `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` so i created a static function to help me achieve it, but, one of the ways to do so doesn't worked as spected, i wonder why does the outcoming string is incomprehensible.

```cs
//#define FORCE_NOT_UTF8

using MemoryMarshal = System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal;
using Unsafe = System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe;
using Encoding = System.Text.Encoding;

static string ForgeString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8Runes)
{
    Span<char> buffer = utf8Runes.Length > 1024
        ? new char[utf8Runes.Length]
        : stackalloc char[1024]
    ;
#if FORCE_NOT_UTF8
    Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(utf8Runes, buffer);
#else
    if (Encoding.Default.BodyName != Encoding.UTF8.BodyName)
    {
        Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(utf8Runes, buffer);
    }
    else if(buffer.Length is <= 1024)
    {
        MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>(utf8Runes).CopyTo(buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        ref readonly var elmnt0 = ref utf8Runes[0];
        ref var ptrSrc = ref Unsafe.AsRef(in elmnt0);
        ref var ptrDst = ref buffer[0];

        for(int i = 0; ptrSrc is not default(byte) && i < utf8Runes.Length; i++)
        {
            ptrDst = (char) ptrSrc;
            ptrSrc = ref Unsafe.Add(ref ptrSrc, 1);
            ptrDst = ref Unsafe.Add(ref ptrDst, 1);
        }
    }
#endif

    Index end = buffer.IndexOf(default(char)) is int index and not -1 ? new(index) : Index.End;

    return new(buffer[..end]);
}

string result1 = default!;
string result2 = default!;

result1 = ForgeString("foobar"u8);
result2 = ForgeString("james james james (...repeating 166 times)"u8);

Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);

//in order to get string result3 its necessary to recompile with compiler symbol FORCE_NOT_UTF8
```

The for loop prints normally, 'James' a bunch of times but, using marshal casting, 'foobar'  produces '潦扯牡.'
What's happing behind `Cast<TFrom,TTo>` to create this unexpected sequence? I thought the idea of it was literally `(T)e`ing each element of a given span.

Comment: Its really funny that '潦扯牡' translates to stupid, i just realised, maybe it's a signal

Comment: `char` is UTF16 not UTF8, as is `string`, so you can't just copy it in, it needs to be decoded from UTF8.

Comment: Yea, looking into the [source](https://shorturl.at/yGOS8) from .NET at `MemoryMarshal.Cast<TFrom, TTo>`, i overlooked that it was reinterpreting the span with a different size, thats the problem, the Type `char` being 16 bits long, while the utf8 encoding threats char as a 8 bits long, which results in an inconprehensible string

Comment: No that's not the issue directly. The issue is you have a UTF8 string in a byte array, but `string` is UTF16. It's simply the wrong bytes.

Comment: Why does it works when casting each byte?

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in PowerShell variant of `.NET`*): `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'utf-16'). GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetBytes( 'foobar'))` returns `潦扯牡`…

Comment: Because casting widens it to double-byte. Note that it won't work if you use smileys or any other character outside the first 127. See eg  https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOc9Hu So even that is broken.

Comment: @JamesJonatah - UTF-8 is a variable-length character encoding in which a given Unicode code point is represented by 1 to 4 bytes as shown in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding).  Conversely [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) *Represents text as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.*  Unlike UTF8 it represents a Unicode value [one or two 16-bit code units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description) -- i.e. 2 or 4 bytes.  Thus it's not binary identical to UTF8 and you can't just cast from one to the other.

Comment: It feels like the universe exploded in front of me, i was dealing with it like it was ASCII, and because i was only using common low value chars it was missleading me to believe it works, thanks! 

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128103) by DPenner1 to [What are Unicode, UTF-8, and UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241348) has a pretty good explainer on the differences between Unicode, UTF8 and UTF16.  Does that answer your question?