# How can I get a character array from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How do you convert a string to a character array in JavaScript?

I'm thinking getting a string like `"Hello world!"` to the array
`['H','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','!']`

Answer (score 566, accepted):

> Note: This is not unicode compliant. `"IU".split('')` results in the
>   4 character array `["I", "�", "�", "u"]` which can lead to dangerous
>   bugs. See answers below for safe alternatives.

Just split it by an empty string.

```js
var output = "Hello world!".split('');
console.log(output);
```

See the [`String.prototype.split()` MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: This doesn't take into account surrogate pairs. `"".split('')` results in `["�", "�"]`.

Comment: See @hakatashi's answer elsewhere in this thread. Hopefully everyone sees this... ***DO NOT USE THIS METHOD, IT'S NOT UNICODE SAFE***

Comment: Bit late to the party. But why would someone ever want to make a array of a string? A string is already an array or am I wrong?

`"randomstring".length;`
`//12`
`"randomstring"[2];`
`//"n"`

Comment: @LuigivanderPal  A string is not an array, but it is very similar. However, it is not similar to an array of characters.   A string is similar to an array of 16-bit numbers, some of which represent characters and some of which represent half of a surrogate pair. For example, `str.length` does not tell you the number of characters in the string, since some characters take more space than others; `str.length` tells you the number of 16-bit numbers.

Answer (score 430):

As [hippietrail suggests](//stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/45331188), [meder's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/4547628) can break
surrogate pairs and misinterpret “characters.” For example:

```js
// DO NOT USE THIS!
const a = ''.split('');
console.log(a);
// Output: ["�","�","�","�","�","�","�","�"]
```

I suggest using one of the following ES2015 features to correctly handle these
character sequences.

### Spread syntax ([already answered](//stackoverflow.com/a/33233956) by insertusernamehere)

```js
const a = [...''];
console.log(a);
```

### [Array.from](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const a = Array.from('');
console.log(a);
```

### [RegExp `u` flag](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015#unicode)

```js
const a = ''.split(/(?=[\s\S])/u);
console.log(a);
```

Use `/(?=[\s\S])/u` instead of `/(?=.)/u` because [`.` does not match
newlines](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1979884). If you are still in ES5.1 era (or if your browser doesn't
handle this regex correctly - like Edge), you can use the following alternative
(transpiled by [Babel](//babeljs.io)). Note, that Babel tries to also handle unmatched
surrogates correctly. However, this doesn't seem to work for unmatched low
surrogates.

```js
const a = ''.split(/(?=(?:[\0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]))/);
console.log(a);
```

### A `for ... of ...` loop

```js
const s = '';
const a = [];
for (const s2 of s) {
   a.push(s2);
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Note that this solution splits some emoji such as `️‍`, and splits combining diacritics mark from characters. If you want to split into grapheme clusters instead of characters, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45238376.

Comment: Note that while not breaking apart surrogate pairs is great, it isn't a general-purpose solution for keeping "characters" (or more accurately, *graphemes*) together. A grapheme can be made up of multiple code points; for instance, the name of the language Devanagari is "देवनागरी", which is read by a native speaker as five graphemes, but takes eight code points to produce...

Comment: This answer is being referred to by the official Mozilla documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 98):

**The `spread` Syntax**

You can use the [spread syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer), an Array Initializer introduced in [ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/):

```
var arr = [...str];
```

---

**Examples**

```js
function a() {
    return arguments;
}

var str = 'Hello World';

var arr1 = [...str],
    arr2 = [...'Hello World'],
    arr3 = new Array(...str),
    arr4 = a(...str);

console.log(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4);
```

The first three result in:

```
["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
```

The last one results in

```
{0: "H", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", 5: " ", 6: "W", 7: "o", 8: "r", 9: "l", 10: "d"}
```

---

**Browser Support**

Check the [ECMAScript ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

---

**Further reading**

- [MDN: Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [ECMAScript 2015 (ES6): 12.2.5 Array Initializer](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer)

`spread` is also referenced as "*`splat`*" (e.g. in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) or [Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) or as "*`scatter`*" (e.g. in [Python](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Think_Python/Tuples#Variable-length_argument_tuples)).

---

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/d4c0rtvf/)

Comment: If you use the spread operator in combination with a compiler to ES5 then this wont work in IE. Take that into consideration. It took me hours to figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 23):

There are (at least) three different things you might conceive of as a "character", and consequently, three different categories of approach you might want to use.

#### Splitting into UTF-16 code units

JavaScript strings were originally invented as sequences of UTF-16 code units, back at a point in history when there was a one-to-one relationship between UTF-16 code units and Unicode code points. The [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of a string measures its length in UTF-16 code units, and when you do `someString[i]` you get the *i*th UTF-16 code unit of `someString`.

Consequently, you can get an array of UTF-16 code units from a string by using a C-style for-loop with an index variable...

```js
const yourString = 'Hello, World!';
const charArray = [];
for (let i=0; i<yourString.length; i++) {
    charArray.push(yourString[i]);
}
console.log(charArray);
```

There are also various short ways to achieve the same thing, like using [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the empty string as a separator:

```js
const charArray = 'Hello, World!'.split('');
console.log(charArray);
```

However, if your string contains code points that are made up of multiple UTF-16 code units, this will split them into individual code units, which may not be what you want. For instance, the string `''` is made up of four unicode code points (code points 0x1D7D8 through 0x1D7DB) which, in UTF-16, are each made up of two UTF-16 code units. If we split that string using the methods above, we'll get an array of eight code units:

```js
const yourString = '';
console.log('First code unit:', yourString[0]);
const charArray = yourString.split('');
console.log('charArray:', charArray);
```

#### Splitting into Unicode Code Points

So, perhaps we want to instead split our string into Unicode Code Points! That's been possible since ECMAScript 2015 added the concept of an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) to the language. Strings are now iterables, and when you iterate over them (e.g. with a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop), you get Unicode code points, not UTF-16 code units:

```js
const yourString = '';
const charArray = [];
for (const char of yourString) {
  charArray.push(char);
}
console.log(charArray);
```

We can shorten this using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which iterates over the iterable it's passed implicitly:

```js
const yourString = '';
const charArray = Array.from(yourString);
console.log(charArray);
```

However, unicode code points are not the largest possible thing that could possibly be considered a "character" *either*. Some examples of things that could reasonably be considered a single "character" but be made up of multiple code points include:

- Accented characters, if the accent is applied with a combining code point
- Flags
- Some emojis

We can see below that if we try to convert a string with such characters into an array via the iteration mechanism above, the characters end up broken up in the resulting array. (In case any of the characters don't render on your system, `yourString` below consists of a capital *A* with an acute accent, followed by the flag of the United Kingdom, followed by a black woman.)

```js
const yourString = 'Á';
const charArray = Array.from(yourString);
console.log(charArray);
```

If we want to keep each of these as a single item in our final array, then we need an array of *graphemes*, not code points.

#### Splitting into graphemes

JavaScript has no built-in support for this - at least not yet. So we need a library that understands and implements the Unicode rules for what combination of code points constitute a grapheme. Fortunately, one exists: orling's [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter). You'll want to install it with npm or, if you're not using npm, download the index.js file and serve it with a `<script>` tag. For this demo, I'll load it from jsDelivr.

grapheme-splitter gives us a `GraphemeSplitter` class with three methods: `splitGraphemes`, `iterateGraphemes`, and `countGraphemes`. Naturally, we want `splitGraphemes`:

```js
const splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
const yourString = 'Á';
const charArray = splitter.splitGraphemes(yourString);
console.log(charArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/grapheme-splitter@1.0.4/index.js"></script>
```

And there we are - an array of three graphemes, which is *probably* what you wanted.

Comment: This was so helpful.  Really saved me on a project I am working on. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 22):

You can use `Array.from`.

```js
var m = "Hello world!";
console.log(Array.from(m))
```

This method has been introduced in ES6.

#### Reference

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

> The `Array.from()` static method creates a new, shallow-copied `Array` instance from an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) or [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#working_with_array-like_objects) object.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the *[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)* function to get the desired output:

```js
var output = Object.assign([], "Hello, world!");
console.log(output);
    // [ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!' ]
```

It is not necessarily right or wrong, just another option.

[Object.assign is described well at the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: That's a long way around to get to `Array.from("Hello, world")`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's a long way around to get to `[..."Hello, world"]`

Comment: `Object.assign([], "")` is `[ "\ud83e", "\udd8a" ]`. This is objectively wrong.

Comment: @SebastianSimon The original question was not that use case.

Comment: @DavidThomas There is no “use case” here. This is exactly the same string processing and encoding. This is about implementing a solution in actual code. Now there’s one solution that’ll work in 90 % of cases and one solution that’ll work in 100 % of cases, but at no additional cost — so it’s obvious which one to pick. `Array.from` etc. are the correct solutions, `Object.assign` etc. are the incorrect ones. The sentiment of providing solutions that just barely work in limited circumstances is harmful to the software industry.

Answer (score 10):

It already is:

```js
var mystring = 'foobar';
console.log(mystring[0]); // Outputs 'f'
console.log(mystring[3]); // Outputs 'b'
```

Or for a more older browser friendly version, use:

```js
var mystring = 'foobar';
console.log(mystring.charAt(3)); // Outputs 'b'
```

Comment: He is really looking to split with an empty string, not reference the original variable.

Comment: -1: it isn't. Try it: `alert("Hello world!" == ['H','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'])`

Comment: Sorry. I guess what I meant to say is: "you can access individual characters by index reference like this without creating a character array".

Comment: Not reliably cross-browser you can't. It's an ECMAScript Fifth Edition feature.

Comment: The cross-browser version is `mystring.charAt(index)`.

Comment: Older versions of IE will trip up on this, at least IE7. Not sure about IE8.

Comment: +1 for `charAt()`--though I'd prefer to use the array-ish variant.  Darn IE.

Comment: No, it isn't. The ability to select elements using brackets notation isn't the only feature of arrays in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7):

Four ways you can convert a string to a character array in JavaScript:

```
const string = 'word';

// Option 1
string.split('');  // ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']

// Option 2
[...string];  // ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']

// Option 3
Array.from(string);  // ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']

// Option 4
Object.assign([], string);  // ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

Comment: This answer would be better if the test string contained Unicode code points greater than U+FFFF. `"".split("")` and `Object.assign([], "")` are `[ "\ud83e", "\udd8a" ]` (due to strings being UTF-16 encoded and therefore indexed by their surrogate byte pairs if necessary); `[ ..."" ]` and `Array.from("")` are equivalent and result in `[ "" ]` (due to these two methods accessing the `Symbol.iterator` property which is Unicode aware).

Answer (score 5):

The ES6 way to split a string into an array character-wise is by using the spread operator. It is simple and nice.

```
array = [...myString];
```

Example:

```js
let myString = "Hello world!"
array = [...myString];
console.log(array);

// another example:

console.log([..."another splitted text"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Mark Amery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796758/5648954) points out in his great answer - splitting on just code points may not be enough, especially for particular emoji characters or composed characters (eg: `ñ` which is made up of two code points `n` and `̃`  which make up the one grapheme). JavaScript has an in-built grapheme segmenter available via the internationalization API ([`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)) called [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter). This can be used to segment a string by different granularities, one of them being the graphemes (ie: user-perceived characters of a string):

```js
const graphemeSplit = str => {
  const segmenter = new Intl.Segmenter("en", {granularity: 'grapheme'});
  const segitr = segmenter.segment(str);
  return Array.from(segitr, ({segment}) => segment);
}
// See browser console for output
console.log("Composite pair test", graphemeSplit("foo  bar mañana mañana"));
console.log("Variation selector test", graphemeSplit("❤️"));
console.log("ZWJ Test:", graphemeSplit("‍❤️‍‍"));
console.log("Multiple Code Points:", graphemeSplit("देवनागरी"));
```

Comment: Also consider using [`normalize`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

Comment: @SebastianSimon thanks - yep normalization is a nice option for dealing with characters that can be precomposed (such as `ñ` above), unfortunately, it won't work on all types of characters made up of multiple code points (such as emojis), but it's a good option if the string being used consists of composable code points 

Comment: Very interesting to learn about this! Alas, [_Can I use_](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_segmenter) suggests that there's no support at all for `Intl.Segmenter` in Firefox yet, so I wouldn't want to use this on a public-facing webpage unless I could find a good polyfill. I am left uncertain about a couple of things after reading this answer: firstly, _is_ there a good polyfill out there in case one wants to use this on the public web, and secondly, [why does `Intl.Segmenter` take a locale parameter and what effect does it have?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75747868/1709587).

Comment: @MarkAmery, `@formatjs Intl.Segmenter` polyfill: https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/main/packages/intl-segmenter see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript/76777557#76777557

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over the length of the string and push the [character at each position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5943726/1366033):

```js
const str = 'Hello World';

const stringToArray = (text) => {
  var chars = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    chars.push(text[i]);
  }
  return chars
}

console.log(stringToArray(str))
```

Comment: While this approach is a little more imperative than declarative, it's the [most performant](https://jsperf.com/string-to-character-array) of any in this thread and deserves more love. *One limitation* to [retrieving a character on a string by position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5943726/1366033) is when dealing with characters past the [Basic Multilingual Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) in unicode such as emojis.  `"".charAt(0)` will return an unusable character

Comment: @KyleMit this seems only true for a short input. [Using a longer input makes `.split("")` the fastest option again](https://jsperf.com/string-to-character-array/2)

Comment: Also `.split("")` seems to be heavily optimized in firefox. While the loop has similar performance in chrome and firefox split is significantly faster in firefox for small and large inputs.

Comment: This method does not work for multi-byte characters! Try it with `str =  '' ` and it will break.

Answer (score 3):

A simple answer:

```js
let str = 'this is string, length is >26';

console.log([...str]);
```

Comment: -1;          this adds nothing that wasn't already included in [hakatashi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717402/1709587).

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
function stringToArray(string) {
  let length = string.length;
  let array = new Array(length);
  while (length--) {
    array[length] = string[length];
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: @KyleMit this seems faster than for i loop + push 
https://jsperf.com/string-to-character-array/3

Answer (score -1):

[Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will do the work as well.

```js
const result = Array.prototype.slice.call("Hello world!");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

convert a string to a char array in js:

```
let x = '246';

// using js split method 
x.split('');  // [ '2', '4', '6' ]   

// using es6 method
[...x];  // [ '2', '4', '6' ]

// using es array method
Array.from(x);  // [ '2', '4', '6' ]
```

Answer (score -2):

One possibility is the next:

```
console.log([1, 2, 3].map(e => Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)).join('').split('').map(e => Math.random() > 0.5 ? e.toUpperCase() : e).join(''));
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?