# String.ToCharArray() equivalent on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to split a string for every character on JavaScript, an equivalent to `String.ToCharArray()` from c#

To later join them with commas.

ex: `"012345"` after splitting -> `"['0','1','2','3','4','5']"` after join -> `"0,1,2,3,4,5"`

So far what I have come across is to loop on every character and manually add the commas (I think this is very slow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a much simpler way to do it:

```
"012345".split('').join(',')
```

The same thing, except with comments:

```
"012345".split('') // Splits into chars, returning ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        .join(',') // Joins each char with a comma, returning "0,1,2,3,4,5"
```

Notice that I pass an empty string to `split()`. If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only the original string, rather than an array containing each character.

Alternatively you could pass nothing to `join()` and it'd use a comma by default, but in cases like this I prefer to be specific.

Don't worry about speed — I'm sure there isn't any appreciable difference. If you're so concerned, there isn't anything wrong with a loop either, though it might be more verbose.

Comment: so simple, yet so amazing. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you could use the "Destructuring" feature:

```
let str = "12345";
//convertion to array:
let strArr = [...str]; // strArr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Array.from is probably more explicit.

```
Array.from("012345").join(',') // returns "0,1,2,3,4,5"
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: this is the best answer here, it has good browser support and is more readable than any others

Answer (score 3):

1. This is a function to make a single word into a char array. Not full proof but does not take much to make it.

   ```
   function toCharArray(str){
        charArray =[];
        for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
             charArray.push(str[i]);
        }

        return charArray;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Array's prototype map method called on a string:

```
Array.prototype.map.call('012345', i => i); 
// ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

See "Using map generically" section of the MDN's `Array.prototype.map` article here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map