# Explode string without separators

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `12345` and I need to explode it to `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Normally, I would use `split`, but there are no separators in here. I could use `substr` (getting `length`, making loops), but I will probably have a lot of those strings, so it may not be good for performance. What can I do?

Comment: already answred here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript

Comment: I didn't find it, but thanks!

Comment: @Tomek, Try with this,
 var myString = "123456";console.log(myString.split(''))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an empty string as a delimiter:

```
"12345".split('');
```