# In javascript how to convert string to array and array to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

In JavaScript and Jquery how to convert the string to array and same array convert to string and check them using typeof method in JavaScript.

Comment: add source `string` and `array`

Comment: You can create JSON object (which is an array, usually consisting of arrays, then stringify it if you want string

Comment: you can make use of array.join(key) to make array to string and you can make use of string.split(key) you can take a look at those functions

Comment: What is this an array *of*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a character array from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-can-i-get-a-character-array-from-a-string)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var arr = "abcdef".split(''); // creates an array from a string

var str = arr.join(''); // creates a string from that above array
```

Answer (score 5):

From String to Array you can Use `split()` Method

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");

console.log(res); // How,are,you,doing,today? it will print
```

From Array to String you can use `Join()` method or `toString()` Method

Answer (score 1):

If you want do it manually, without any JavaScript methods. Try the below

**String to Array**

```
var str = "STRING";
var arr = [];
for(int i=0; i<=str.length; i++)
    arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
```

**Array to String**

```
var str = "";
var arr = ["S","T","R","I","G"];
for(int i=0; i<=arr.length; i++)
    str +=arr.charAt(i);
```