# Split Chinese Characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, utf-8, split

How can I split foreign characters, such as Chinese, into separate array values using JavaScript?

`split()` seems to work well with English, but not so much with Chinese. See below result of two strings

a) Hello There

b) 你好吗

```
splitString = text.split(" ");

RESULT: ["hello", "there"] 
RESULT: ["你好吗"]
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about the nature of "words" in Chinese. Chinese can be considered to have a concept of "words", but it is not necessarily well-defined. You are looking for the idea of "segmentation", but segmentation in Chinese (and other languages without spaces, including Thai, Korean, and Japanese) is a quite complex linguistic task, which as another commenter mentioned, is implemented in libraries. On the other hand, if you merely want to split by character, then `String#split` does exactly what you want in most cases.

Comment: Note that all answers in this question use character split, which is the same as [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do that *reliably* using built-in ES5 facilities without using any 3rd party libraries.

The correct way using vanilla JS is to use ES2015 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
let splitString = [...text];
```

Examples of strings which would cause the `split`-based solutions to fail:

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting on a space char (which there aren't any in the chinese string), try splitting on an empty string "", which should split each char into its own element.

Comment: It will break for some multibyte characters like ``: `''.split('')` --- outputs `["", ""]` (array of 2 empty strings)

Comment: Interesting. Good to know for the future.

Comment: @zerkms no, it gives me ["\ud840","\udc01"]

Comment: @DanD. the output format has now obviously changed. It does not change the fact it's still the wrong result.