# Javascript: String of text to array of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to change a huge string into the array of chars. In other languages there is .toCharArray(). I've used split to take dots, commas an spaces from the string and make string array, but I get only separated words and don't know how to make from them a char array. or how to add another regular expression to separate word? my main goal is something else, but I need this one first. thanks

```
var str = " If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only  the original string, rather than an array containing each character."
str = str.toLowerCase();
str = str.split(/[ ,.]+/);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Comment: `split` method returns array of `words` itself, are you trying to make char array from each and every word inside that `str` array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to change a huge string into the array of chars.

This will do

```
str = str.toLowerCase().split("");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var charArray[];
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    charArray.push(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply use:

```
var charArray = str.split("");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
var strAr = str.replace(/ /g,' ').toLowerCase().split("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String#replace` with regex and `String#split`.

```
arrChar = str.replace(/[', ]/g,"").split('');
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = " If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only  the original string, rather than an array containing each character.";

var arrChar = str.replace(/[', ]/g,"").split('');

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrChar, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Add character in `[]` which you want to remove from string.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to replace the `,` and `.` then you can split it:

```js
var str = " If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only  the original string, rather than an array containing each character."
var strarr = str.replace(/[\s,.]+/g, "").split("");

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(strarr, 0, 4)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The split() method is used to split a string into an array of
>   substrings, and returns the new array.
>
> **Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is
>   split between each character**.
>
> Note: The split() method does not change the original string.

Please read the link:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this

```js
var coolString,
    charArray,
    charArrayWithoutSpecials,
    output;

coolString = "If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only  the original string, rather than an array containing each character.";

// does the magic, uses string as an array to slice
charArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(coolString);

// let's do this w/o specials
charArrayWithoutSpecials = Array.prototype.slice.call(coolString.replace(/[', ]/g,""))


// printing it here
output = "<b>With special chars:</b> " + JSON.stringify(charArray);
output += "<br/><br/>";
output += "<b>With special chars:</b> " + JSON.stringify(charArrayWithoutSpecials)
document.write(output);
```

another way would be

```
[].slice.call(coolString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for. Ignoring all symbols and spaces and adding all characters in to an array with lower case.

```js
var str = " If you don't pass anything, you'll get an array containing only  the original string, rather than an array containing each character."
str = str.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase().split("");

alert(str);
```