# Can i further break an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have the following array-
var x= ["hello"];

Can i further break it into a character array like this one-
var x_character= ["h","e","l","l","o"];

if not, can you tell me how to know the character length of the x array..

Comment: Yes it is possible and it is not hard to find an answer with a search

Comment: For splitting the string, [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the .length method to get the information you are after (using unusual characters or such)?

Comment: you can simply use the length function to find the charater length of array x.

Comment: To find the total length of all strings in the array (assuming there are potentially more than 1). Start a variable at `0`, loop through the array, and add to the variable the `length` of each string. Try [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to condense all of that to a single expression. (The focus on splitting the string seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if the length is your goal.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the .split() method:

```
var x = ["hello"]
x[0].split("")
```

Returns the array `["h","e","l","l","o"]`. The `""` argument means to split the string at each empty substring.

Comment: what if i want to do this with all the elements and not just the one in 0 index?

Comment: @PadamChopra What's your end goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new empty array, iterate through the original array and push each character into the new array. To get the length of the original array - use "x.length" (ie: "var arrayLength=x.length";)

```
var x = ["hello"];
var x_character=[];

for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
    var x_character.push(x[i])
  }
```