# Get all substrings of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function to get all of the substrings from a string in JavaScript. I know it's not correct but I feel like I am going about it  the right way. Any advice would be great.

```
 var theString     = 'somerandomword',
     allSubstrings = []; 

getAllSubstrings(theString);

function getAllSubstrings(str) {

  var start = 1;

  for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++  ) {

     allSubstrings.push( str.substring(start,i) ); 

  }

} 

console.log(allSubstrings)
```

Edit: Apologies if my question is unclear. By substring I mean all combinations of letters from the string (do not have to be actual words) So if the string was 'abc' you could have [a, ab, abc, b, ba, bac etc...] Thank you for all the responses.

Comment: What do you mean by "all" the substrings?

Comment: What output you expect?

Comment: This should be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with 'substrings'. If you're trying to get each word as its own value you would have to split the string specifically at A, B, C.

But what if the word is not 'somerandomword'? They you would either have to use a dictionary or another array of words you would like your function to split by. Each of these words cannot be defined as a 'word'.

Comment: I wonder, is 'bac' a substring of 'abc' ?!

Comment: What would be a better way to phrase this question and i'll update it.

Comment: Your new edit does clarify things. I'm curious though -- why would you would want to do this? :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need two nested loop for the sub strings.

```js
function getAllSubstrings(str) {
  var i, j, result = [];

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < str.length + 1; j++) {
          result.push(str.slice(i, j));
      }
  }
  return result;
}

var theString = 'somerandomword';
console.log(getAllSubstrings(theString));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this solution gives only parts of the string, but does no make permutations of it.

Comment: This doesn't produce every substring possible like "os". It only moves to the right.

Comment: @Badmaash, do you wnat a permutation of all characters instead?

Comment: Not me but I think that's exactly what questioner is looking for. Look at his Edit :)

Comment: @Badmash Left to right only

Answer (score 3):

A modified version of Accepted Answer. In order to give the minimum string length for permutation

```js
function getAllSubstrings(str, size) {
  var i, j, result = [];
  size = (size || 0);
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (j = str.length; j - i >= size; j--) {
      result.push(str.slice(i, j));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var theString = 'somerandomword';
console.log(getAllSubstrings(theString, 6));
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a recursive solution to the problem

```js
let result = [];

function subsetsOfString(str, curr = '', index = 0) {
  if (index == str.length) {
    result.push(curr);
    return result;
  }
  subsetsOfString(str, curr, index + 1);
  subsetsOfString(str, curr + str[index], index + 1);
}

subsetsOfString("somerandomword");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer with the use of substring function.

```js
function getAllSubstrings(str) {
  var res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j <= str.length; j++) {
      res.push(str.substring(i, j));
    }
  }
  return res;
}
var word = "randomword";
console.log(getAllSubstrings(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple approach to find all substrings

```js
    var arr = "abcde";

     for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){

      for(let j=i; j < arr.length; j++){

      let bag ="";
      for(let k=i; k<j; k++){
       bag = bag + arr[k]
    }
    console.log(bag)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateALlSubstrings(N,str){
    
    for(let i=0; i<N; i++){

        for(let j=i+1; j<=N; j++){

            console.log(str.substring(i, j));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings inherently have a length property. having to input `N` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getSubstrings(s){
    //if string passed is null or undefined or empty string
    if(!s)   return []; 

    let substrings = [];

    for(let length = 1 ; length <= s.length; length++){
        for(let  i = 0 ; (i + length) <= s.length ; i++){
            substrings.push(s.substr(i, length));
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}
```