# How to code an recursion function from an iterative approach?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, iterator, palindrome

How would I be able to code the same code below while using recursion, I did it with an iterative approach and I would really appreciate it if someone can help me code it using recursion thankyou!
Here's my code:

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  function checkForPalindrome(chunk) { 
    let chunkArray = [];
    for (const letter of chunk) { 
      chunkArray.push(letter);
    }
    if (chunkArray.reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0, index2 = 2; index1 <= word.length; index1++, (index2 = index1 + 2)) {
    for (; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}

returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd");
```

Comment: Do you really need to ask that question again? You asked [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64796628/1244884) and possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64596115/1244884) is coming from another account of yours

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count all the palindromes in a string using recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64596115/how-to-count-all-the-palindromes-in-a-string-using-recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write `checkForPalindrome` recursively since it's trivial to do:

```js
function checkForPalindrome(str) {
  // we can use .split("") to convert to an array of characters
  return str.split("").reverse().join("") == str;
}

function palindromesAtStart(str) {
  // lengths 0 and 1 can't be palindromes
  if (str.length < 2) {
    return 0;
  }
  // if it's a palindrome add 1
  const diff = checkForPalindrome(str) ? 1 : 0;
  // now shorten the string and check again
  return diff + palindromesAtStart(str.slice(0, -1));
}

function returnNumberOfPalindromes(str) {
  if (str.length < 2) {
    return 0;
  }
  // total palindromes is palindromes at start plus palindromes not at start
  return palindromesAtStart(str) + returnNumberOfPalindromes(str.slice(1));
}


console.log(returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak"));
console.log(returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya"));
console.log(returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal"));
console.log(returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd"));
```

Essentially, the palindromes in the string can either include the first index, or not include the first index. So, we can write a simple recursive function (`palindromesAtStart`) to count the number of palindromes which include the first index and add that to the number of palindromes which don't include the first index.

Comment: how would I run this?

Comment: as in which function would I call onto @Aplet123

Comment: It's the function with the same name, `returnNumberOfPalindromes`.

Comment: I don't log the return value. If you want it, you should log it yourself.

Comment: how can I log it? @Aplet123

Comment: `console.log` to log

Comment: By calling [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) on the result.

Comment: @Aplet123, wait why is it returning undefined?

Comment: `console.log` returns undefined and logs the result. If you want to log and return it, then save the return value to a variable, log it, then return it.

Answer (score 2):

## A series of refactorings

Over a series of refactorings, we're going to end up with this code:

```js
const isPalindrome = (s) =>  
  s.length == 0 ? true : s[0] === s[s.length - 1] && isPalindrome(s.slice(1, -1))

const countPalindromicPrefixes = (s) =>
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : (isPalindrome(s) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(s.slice (0, -1)) 

const countPalindromes = (s) => 
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : countPalindromicPrefixes(s) + countPalindromes(s.slice(1))


console .log (countPalindromes ("kayak"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("aya"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("appal"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("addadaadd"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("madamimadam"));
```

Each step has a snippet (hidden by default so this isn't *too* long) showing that we haven't broken anything so far.

### Starting Point

The initial code looks like this:

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  function checkForPalindrome(chunk) { 
    let chunkArray = [];
    for (const letter of chunk) { 
      chunkArray.push(letter);
    }
    if (chunkArray.reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0, index2 = 2; index1 <= word.length; index1++, (index2 = index1 + 2)) {
    for (; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}
```

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  function checkForPalindrome(chunk) { 
    let chunkArray = [];
    for (const letter of chunk) { 
      chunkArray.push(letter);
    }
    if (chunkArray.reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0, index2 = 2; index1 <= word.length; index1++, (index2 = index1 + 2)) {
    for (; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}

returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd");
```

### Fixing the `for`-loops

There is something very odd about updating the initial index of the inner loop as part of the increment of outer one.  This is much more common, and I dare say, much more logical:

```js
  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
```

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  function checkForPalindrome (chunk) { 
    if (chunk.split('').reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}

returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("madamimadam");
```

### Simplifying `checkForPalindrome`

Much of the work being done in `checkForPalindrome` is unnecessary.  [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) already turns a string into an array of characters.  So we can change that part to just:

```
  function checkForPalindrome (chunk) { 
    if (chunk.split('').reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
```

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  function checkForPalindrome (chunk) { 
    if (chunk.split('').reverse().join('') === chunk) {
      tally += 1;
    }
  }
  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      checkForPalindrome(chunk);
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}

returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("madamimadam");
```

### Make local function a pure function

Our internal function `checkForPalindrome` is not returning a value.  Instead, it is updating the state of `tally`.  That makes it harder to understand.  Let's change that to make `checkForPalindrome` return `true` or `false`, and update `tally` based on that result:

```js
  function checkForPalindrome (chunk) { 
    return chunk.split('').reverse().join('') === chunk
  }
```

```
      if (checkForPalindrome(chunk)) {
        tally += 1
      }
```

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {

  function checkForPalindrome (chunk) { 
    return chunk.split('').reverse().join('') === chunk
  }

  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      if (checkForPalindrome(chunk)) {
        tally += 1
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(tally);
}

returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd");
returnNumberOfPalindromes("madamimadam");
```

### Pulling that internal function out

Still focused on `checkForPalindrome`, we can note that it's now a useful function to determine if a string is a palindrome.  So we might as well pull it out of the guts of our main function and make it stand-alone.

But a common convention for a function returning `true` or `false` is to name it starting with `is`.  In this case, `isPalindrome` definitely makes more sense.  So we change to this:

```js
function isPalindrome (word) { 
  return word.split('').reverse().join('') === word
}
```

and

```js
      if (isPalindrome(chunk)) {
        tally += 1
      }
```

```js
function isPalindrome (word) { 
  return word.split('').reverse().join('') === word
}

function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {

  let tally = 0;

  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      if (isPalindrome(chunk)) {
        tally += 1
      }
    }
  }
  return tally;
}

console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd"));  //=> 7
```

### Turning this recursive

Now for the big step.  We want to make this recursive.  Let's examine what our main loop is doing:

```js
  for (let index1 = 0; index1 <= word.length; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = index1 + 2; index2 <= word.length; index2++) { 
      let chunk = word.slice(index1, index2); 
      if (isPalindrome(chunk)) {
        tally += 1
      }
    }
  }
```

This code is looping twice through the indices, finding all the substrings starting at index 0, then all starting at index 1, then all starting at index 2, etc.  For each one it tests if the string is a palindrome, and if it is, we increment the tally.

This sort of double-looping will almost certainly mean that we have a double recursion going on too.  So we can think about it as having two functions.

One function takes a string and looks at all the prefixes of that string (for instance for "goat", the prefixes would be "goat", "goa", "go", and "g") and counts the number of those that are palindromes.  If the word is fewer than two characters long, then it has no palindromes and we return `0`, and otherwise we include `1` if the word is a palindrome, `0` if it's not and add it to the result of a recursive call that drops off the last character:

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return (isPalindrome(word) ? 1 : 0) + returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word.slice(0, -1)) 
}
```

The second function recurs on the *beginning* of the string.  Again if the word is fewer than two characters long, we again return `0`.  Otherwise we add the result of calling the prefix function to a recursive call on the string formed by dropping our first character:

```js
function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word) + returnNumberOfPalindromes(word.slice(1))
}
```

```js
function isPalindrome(word) { 
  return word.split('').reverse().join('') === word
}

function returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return (isPalindrome(word) ? 1 : 0) + returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word.slice(0, -1)) 
}

function returnNumberOfPalindromes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return returnNumberOfPalindromicPrefixes(word) + returnNumberOfPalindromes(word.slice(1))
}

console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("kayak"));
console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("aya"));
console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("appal"));
console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("addadaadd"));
console .log (returnNumberOfPalindromes("madamimadam"));
```

### Interlude

At this point we have reasonable code.  We have refactored it into recursive functions that are fairly logical and fairly clear.  (It's also very similar to the answer from Applet123.)

This may be plenty for you (or for your instructor.)

But I think there are more useful changes to be made.  Think of the next few steps as nice-to-haves.

### Function naming

This may sound trivial, but the names `returnNumberOf<Whatever>` are pretty horrible.  Much better would be `count<Whatever>`, `numberOf<Whatever>` possibly `sizeOf<Whatever>`.

I will choose the first one, which will give us the names `countPalindromicPrefixes` and `countPalindromes`.

```js
function isPalindrome (word) { 
  return word.split('').reverse().join('') === word
}

function countPalindromicPrefixes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return (isPalindrome(word) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(word.slice(0, -1)) 
}

function countPalindromes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return countPalindromicPrefixes(word) + countPalindromes(word.slice(1))
}

console .log (countPalindromes("kayak"));
console .log (countPalindromes("aya"));
console .log (countPalindromes("appal"));
console .log (countPalindromes("addadaadd"));
console .log (countPalindromes("madamimadam"));
```

### More modern JS

Using arrow functions rather than function declarations cleans up a lot of code.  [Conditional (ternary) operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)  also do.  Using these we can turn something like this:

```js
function countPalindromes(word) {
  if (word .length < 2) {
    return 0
  }
  return countPalindromicPrefixes(word) + countPalindromes(word.slice(1))
}
```

into this:

```js
const countPalindromes = (word) => 
  word .length < 2 ? 0 : countPalindromicPrefixes(word) + countPalindromes(word.slice(1))
```

and do something similar for the other functions.

```js
const isPalindrome = (word) =>  
  word.split('').reverse().join('') === word

const countPalindromicPrefixes = (word) =>
  word.length < 2 ? 0 : (isPalindrome(word) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(word.slice(0, -1)) 

const countPalindromes = (word) => 
  word.length < 2 ? 0 : countPalindromicPrefixes(word) + countPalindromes(word.slice(1))


console .log (countPalindromes ("kayak"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("aya"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("appal"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("addadaadd"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("madamimadam"));
```

### Parameter naming

We're using the parameter name "word" here for our functions.  But do we truly mean for this to be a word?  The sentence "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama!" is widely described as a palindrome.  (While it doesn't fit our test, we could easily fix it up to do so by lowercasing the value and removing any non alphabetic characters before doing the current test.)  And in fact, I added a test case to these, which captures a version of another classic palindrome, "Madam, I'm Adam."

So the input could be a word or a sentence?  Perhaps a phrase as well?  People talk sometimes about numbers being palindromic, ones such as 2112. So "word" is not the right name for these.  Ours seems to take an arbitrary string.  So we should rename the parameter to something capturing that.  Perhaps "str"?  Perhaps "string"?  I'm going to suggest something more radical.  We really don't know the type, and it's a one-line function, so a single-character name that still gives a flavor of "string" seems perfectly reasonable here.  I will choose "s".  Do note that there are those who abhor this idea.  That might include your instructor, so be careful.  (If someone objects, you can always point them to an article on this idea, [Descriptive Variable Names: A Code Smell](https://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic), by John DeGoes.  But they might still start throwing things at you, so be wary.)

So we might write these this way:

```js
const countPalindromicPrefixes = (s) =>
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : (isPalindrome(s) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(s.slice(0, -1))
```

```js
const isPalindrome = (s) =>  
  s.split('').reverse ().join('') === s

const countPalindromicPrefixes = (s) =>
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : (isPalindrome(s) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(s.slice(0, -1)) 

const countPalindromes = (s) => 
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : countPalindromicPrefixes(s) + countPalindromes(s .slice(1))


console .log (countPalindromes ("kayak"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("aya"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("appal"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("addadaadd"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("madamimadam"));
```

### Do all the things recursive

I wouldn't do the following except for a class assignment.  We already have a working version of `isPalindrome`, one that is readable and efficient.  But since this is clearly a recursion assignment, it might be nice to write a recursive version of `isPalindrome` as well.

To do that, we can think about this recursively by noting that a string is a palindrome if the first and last characters match and the string in between is also a palindrome.  The empty string is here considered a palindrome, as is a single-character string.  (The first and last characters in this case, point to the same place, so of course they're the same.)  We could write it like this:

```js
const isPalindrome = (s) =>  
  s.length == 0 ? true : s[0] === s[s.length - 1] && isPalindrome(s.slice(1, -1))
```

Note that for the general problem here, we didn't consider 1-character substrings as palindromes, but that's handled in the main functions.  `isPalindrome` happily reports them as such, which seems appropriate.

```js
const isPalindrome = (s) =>  
  s.length == 0 ? true : s[0] === s[s.length - 1] && isPalindrome(s.slice(1, -1))

const countPalindromicPrefixes = (s) =>
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : (isPalindrome(s) ? 1 : 0) + countPalindromicPrefixes(s.slice (0, -1)) 

const countPalindromes = (s) => 
  s.length < 2 ? 0 : countPalindromicPrefixes(s) + countPalindromes(s.slice(1))


console .log (countPalindromes ("kayak"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("aya"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("appal"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("addadaadd"));
console .log (countPalindromes ("madamimadam"));
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I originally wrote this function and reading your refactoring of (before you make a recursive version from it) has been very useful to me so thank-you for that. Do you think it's even worth having `isPalindrome` a separate function? Does it help readability? Thanks again

Comment: Of course readability is like beauty, it's in the eye of the beholder.  But to my mind, this is a clear *yes*.  This is quite a bit more readable with that helper function.  But there is another advantage. It begins to build a collection of useful functions.  Say the next assignment asked you to filter a list of strings to find the palindromes of at least five characters. Sure.  Here: `const longerPalindromes = (strings) => strings .filter (s => isPalindrome (s) && s .length >= 5)`.  Boom!  We can do this quickly because we already have `isPalindrome` defined.