# How to get length of string in javascript without using native length method

Tags: javascript

I am working on a practice problem:

> Return the length of a string without using javascript's native `string.length` method.

The only ways I could think of would be `substring` or `slice`, but I'm stumped.

Comment: What's your actual question now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @KyleMuir not a duplicate. like nnnnnn said, i cant use any native length methods. that includes arrays

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can loop over the string, testing to see whether there is a non-`undefined` value at each index (as soon as you get an `undefined` value you've run past the end of the string):

```js
function strLength(s) {
  var length = 0;
  while (s[length] !== undefined)
    length++;
  return length;
}

console.log(strLength("Hello")); // 5
console.log(strLength("")); // 0
```

(I'm assuming that if you're not allowed to use the native string `.length` property that you probably shouldn't use the array `.length` property either with `str.split("").length`...)

Comment: i actually tried a variation of that using a `for-loop` and it failed the tests due to both of your correct assumptions. which is why i was originally looking for how to do this in either `slice` or `substring`. this is what it should have been

Answer (score 5):

Given that this is a practice problem, I suspect the OP may not want ES6/ES2015, but, just in case that's an option, and/or for whoever else is looking at this, here's a concise modern approach:

```js
const str = "Hello world!";

console.log([...str].reduce(a => a+1, 0));
```

*(When I posted this, no other answer had proposed this solution. However, I had missed the fact that @MarkoGrešak had essentially proposed this exact solution in a comment to another question.)*

Comment: Even with `str.split("")` and a traditional non-arrow function reducer this would still be pretty concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread element, `Array.prototype.keys()` iterator, `Array.prototype.pop()`

```js
var str = "abc";
var len = [...[0,...str].keys()].pop();
console.log(len, str.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The briefest have been able to achieve so far using `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.pop()` and checking for empty string. Approach could probably be improved further.

```
var len = str === "" ? 0 : +Object.keys(str).pop()+1;
```

---

@nnnnnnn utilizes the two methods at above far exceeding the initial attempt in brevity and addressing case of empty string.

```
var len = +Object.keys(str+' ').pop();
```

Comment: You could save a character with `==` instead of `===`. You could save some pixels with `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Also removing eight space characters from line. Still have sense the line can be further reduced

Comment: `var len = (+Object.keys(str).pop()+1)||0`

Comment: @nnnnnn There is that `OR` conjured at previous post.

Comment: `var len = +Object.keys(str+' ').pop()` - You were really onto something with the popping keys concept.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be iterating through a split string like so:

```
var count = 0;
Array.from("string here".split("")).forEach(function(){count++});
```

Tip from Marko below in the comments to use the `reduce` function to shorten it to:

```
var count = Array.from("string here".split("")).reduce(function(count){return count+1}, 0);
```

Comment: If you're going to do it like that, at least use `.reduce(function(count) { return count + 1}, 0)`.

Comment: That's a good thought, have been meaning to use the reduce function more recently.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak, I had checked the other answers before I posted mine, but I hadn't seen your comment which proposed the same solution I did. Just wanting to give credit where it's due.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewWillems! @andrew196 the idea of `reduce` is not to only shorten the code, but also to avoid having an external state, but keep everything local to the reduce callback function. This way you don't have to worry about resetting the state before computing the length multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkoGrešak. Good to know

Answer (score 0):

You could use array.length so you answer the question not using the native string.length.

```
var Str = "Hello world!";
const CountAr = Str.split("").length;
console.log(CountAr);
/*12*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringLength(str) {
  var count = 0;
  var index = 0;

  while(string[index] !== undefined){
    count += 1;
    index += 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: While code only answers may answer the question, you should explain them to those who may not understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.  If you start with '', it won't go into the while loop, and you'll just return 0.

```
function getStringLength(string) {
  var idx = 0;
  while (string[idx] !== undefined) {
    idx += 1;
  }
  return idx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
function  length(str) {
    str = str.split(''); 
    var length = 0;
    str.forEach(function(element) { 
    length++;  
    });
    return length;    
}
```

length('hello'); // output 5

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it

```
function getStringLength(str){
  var count = 0;
  for(var letter in str){
    count += 1;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(getStringLength('Mississippi')) // 11
console.log(getStringLength('')) // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The for in loop is the way to go I think. You can use slice or substring but for in loops can count strings easily too.

```
function getStringLength(string) {
      var length = 0;
      for (var i in string){
        length++;
      }
      return length;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with
I have used a while loop for getting the length of the input
Sharing Two approaches with a while loop

**Approach no 1**

```js
    function getLength(input) {
        if(!input){
          return 'please provide input'
        }
        let i = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (input[i]) {
                i += 1
            }else{
                break
            }
        }
        return i
    }
    
console.log(getLength([1, 5, 3, 7, 8])) // 5
console.log(getLength("Hare Krishna")) // 12
```

Output
*5 (for array)

12 (for string)*

**Approach no 2**

```js
function getLength(input){
  let i = 0;
  while(input[i] !== undefined){
    i++;
  }
  return i
}

console.log(getLength([1,2,3,48,8,9])) // 6
```

Output
*6 (for array)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStringLength(string) {
// Do NOT use any native 'length' methods.
// You might consider using 'substring' or 'slice' as alternatives.
 
  let i = 0;
  while (Number(string.slice(i, i+1)) !== 0) {
    i++;
 } return i;
}

var output = getStringLength('hello');
console.log(output); // --> 5
```

Comment: this is a code only answer. Consider adding a helpful description.