# How to split sentence into letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, loops

I want to split text which was provided by user into single characters and then edit them.
I used RegEx to divide whole sentence into words and then into characters, but finally I got array of arrays :/

Code (check console):

```js
function showLetters() {
  const simpleText = 'Hello my friends';
  let words = simpleText.split(/\W+/),
      letters = words.map(word => {
        return word.match(/\S/g).join();
      });

  console.log(letters);
}

showLetters();
```

I want to know how can I get to this letters in finall array.
I beg for help, i'm newbie

Comment: Can you update the question with an expected input output combination?

Comment: _“I want to know how can I get to this letters in finall array”_ - so your question is basically, how do I access elements in a JavaScript array? Then you should probably be reading up on basics like that in some beginner’s tutorial right now, rather than come asking here …? This site is not really a teaching ground for such basics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get a string to a character array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-do-you-get-a-string-to-a-character-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @CBroe when i said finall i meant that i got arrays in array
i know how to loop through standard array...

Answer (score 2):

RegEx isn't needed here I don't think, if I understand you correctly this is what you need:

```js
function showLetters() {
  const simpleText = "Hello my friends";
  let letters = simpleText.split("").filter(letter => letter !== " ");

  console.log(letters);
}

showLetters();
```

If you want the 'Blank Spaces' to remain as entities within the array, just remove the .filter part.

Comment: Thanks, i don't get it why i tried to loop it

Answer (score 1):

Just split on an optional white space, which will return all letters except white space.

```js
function showLetters() {
  const simpleText = 'Hello my friends';
  let letters = simpleText.split(/\s?/);
  console.log(letters);
}

showLetters();
```

Comment: Thank you, but there's another question, how can i join letters from this array into words i had on beginning

Comment: Can you keep the original sentence? What happens after you put the letters in an array? Are they modified in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Might it not be simpler to regex replace all nonword chars with nothing, then split on nothing (Or use Array.from(string))?

```
str.replace(/\W/gi, "").split("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showLetters() {
  const simpleText = 'Hello my friends';
  let words = simpleText.split("");

  console.log(words);
}

showLetters();
```

You'll get every character including white space in `words` array, so when you join them using `.join("")` you'll get words separated by white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<html>
    <body>
    
    <button onclick="showLetters()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>

            function showLetters() {

            var simpleText = "Hello my friends";
            var letters  = simpleText.split("");

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = letters;
            
            }

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your contribution but please make sure that you explain what changes you made and how it affects the existing code.