# Is there a way to convert a string of numbers like this "1,2,3,4" to an array in js?

Tags: javascript

Im working on a simple program and im trying to put user input in it and i want to know if theres an easy way of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the comma and use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert each element to a number.

```
str.split(",").map(a=>+a);
```

```js
const str = "1,2,3,4";
const arr = str.split(",").map(a=>+a);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer it should work if i implement it correctly. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: @The_Duck_Lord No problem.

Comment: did it. Also found other ways of splitting strings that are not numbers into arrays with the [spreadSyntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33233956/2864502) though this one is used for splitting letters in a string. Like `hello` to [`h`,`e`,`l`,`l`,`o`] .