# How convert a string to type Uint8Array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

- How do I convert a string to a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) in node?
- I don't normally develop in Javascript and this is driving me nuts. They offer a conversion `Uint8Array.toString()` but not the other way around. Does anyone know of an easy way for me to do this without creating my own parser?
- I have seen some other answers to this, but they don't seem to address this specific class type

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding). The [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) class has implemented the [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) interface in Node since [v4.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v4.x/api/buffer.html). You can also optionally specify an encoding with which to do string processing in both directions, i.e. [`buffer.toString([encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Answer (score 11):

```
Uint8Array.from(text.split('').map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0)));
```

or (appears about 18% faster):

```
Uint8Array.from(Array.from(text).map(letter => letter.charCodeAt(0)));
```

Note: These only work for ASCII, so all the letters are modulo 256, so if you try with Russian text, it won't work.

Comment: Answers with explanation of code generally do better than code dumps which leave it to others to interpret. Also, `text.split('')` doesn't work well for Unicode strings; see [How to get character array from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4547609/215552)

Comment: Well you replied just as I was editing the answer.
Indeed it's not good for unicode but this method is very simple and fast and might be exactly what he's looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Why not simply using:

```
const resEncodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode(message)
```