# Google Script / Javascript includes() function not matching when expected with valid input

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm struggling to figure out why the Javascript includes() function I'm using here isn't matching and returning `true`. The code is used in a Google Script on a Google Sheet to populate some cell values. Here's the relevant code from the full script:

```
const currentYear = getCurrentYear();

//Get current year from active sheet name
function getCurrentYear(){

  year = sheetName.slice(-7, -2);
  return year; //returns "2020"

}

//Return Current Control File ID
function getCurrentControlFileId(){
  
  const controlFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(controlFolderId);
  const controlFiles = controlFolder.getFiles();
  
  while (controlFiles.hasNext()){
    let controlFile = controlFiles.next();
    let currentControlFileName = controlFile.getName(); // Evaluates to "CONTROL 2020"
    let searchString = `${currentYear}`; // Evaluates to "2020"
    //Have also tried:
    //let searchString = currentYear; 
    
    if (currentControlFileName.includes(searchString)){
      let controlFileId = controlFile.getId();
      return controlFileId;
    }
  }
  
}
```

`controlFile.getName().includes(searchString)` returns `false` even though `controlFile.getName()` value is "CONTROL 2020" and `searchString` value is "2020". Both are strings. If I manually enter "2020" into the `if` statement conditions like this:

`controlFile.getName().includes("2020")` it returns true and works as expected, returning the ID string. I've also tried wrapping `currentYear` and `controlFile.getName()` in `String()` but it still returns false. I really can't see what the problem is here, would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can't reproduce the situation your are describing. Can you test this: `Logger.log(searchString==="2020")` ? If that returns false, then there is an issue in `searchString`.

Comment: @Marios Thanks for suggestions. In the Stackdriver logs it's coming back as false. Very odd since searchString returns what looks like "2020" but isn't interpreted that way. Any idea?

Comment: Can you check then : `Logger.log(typeof searchString)` ? also try to see if the value is 2020 and not "2020" by `Logger.log(searchString)`

Comment: @Marios The logger says typeof is String and the value itself is "2020" (without quotes).

Comment: I've added: 'ui.alert(typeof currentControlFileName);
    ui.alert(currentControlFileName);
    Logger.log(typeof currentControlFileName);
    Logger.log(currentControlFileName);' and the logger shows they are both strings and the values are "2020" for searchString and "CONTROL 2020" for currentControlFileName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Most likely `year` includes an empty space

You can doublecheck it with `Logger.log(year.length);`.

Beware that the when using [array.slice(start, end)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) that the end index is the first element that it not included in your result. So, if you expect as output "2020" (corresponding to `year.length=4`):

`end-start` should equal to `4`.

If your sheet name is something like `"XXX 2020 YY"` you should modify the definition of `year` to

`year = sheetName.slice(-7, -3);`

Comment: This works which is great, thanks very much, I've spent hours trying to fix this but I'm confused as to why the includes() function didn't work because "CONTROL 2020" did include " 2020" (with the space in front of the 2020) so it should have matched? Or did the way I sliced it cause a space after the 2020 like: "2020 " which doesnt match?

Comment: What is your sheet name? If you sliced it to "2020 " then it won't match.

Comment: The sheet name is "CONTROL 2020" and I was searching for "2020". sheetName.slice(-7, -2) seemed to return "2020" so are you saying that it would have introduced a space before or after the "2020"? If before then it should still have matched.

Comment: @Diagonali It sure wasn't `CONTROL 2020`. "CONTROL 2020".slice(-7,-2) === "OL 20" and not 2020

Comment: In addition to what @TheMaster said: Should you want to extract `2020` from `CONTROL 2020` you should query for `year = sheetName.slice(-4);`. Mind you that in this case you could also use a simplier approach, e.g. `year = sheetName.split(" ")[1];`

Comment: I was incorrect in saying it was "CONTROL 2020" - it was actually "ORDERBOOK 2020 ". I think maybe the emoji was causing an issue?

Comment: Must be. If there is a space between `2020` and the emoji - one more reason to use `year = sheetName.split(" ")[1];`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @Diagonali Emojis are sometimes  combination of emojis. This emoji is actually 2 characters: `console.log("".length)`

Comment: We're way offtopic, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59796758/) a interesting answer. cc@Diagonali

Comment: That explains it, thanks! I really wanted to understand why it didn't work rather than just avoid the error. @ziganotschka, that's good to know going forward, very much appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: @TheMaster: that's useful to know!