# Converting every other letter to upper and lower case in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a name string 'talhakhan' to 'TaLhaKhAn'. I can loop through the entire variable but I am facing issue in assignment. Please check my code:

```js
var name = 'talhakhan';
var counter = true;
for (var e = 0; e < name.length; e++) {
  if (counter)
    name.charAt(e) = name.charAt(e).toUpperCase();
  else
    name.charAt(e) = name.charAt(e).toLowerCase();
  counter = false;
}
```

error:

> VM704:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
> at :1:11

Comment: `name.charAt(e)` calls a function which returns a value. You can't assign a value to a function call.

Comment: Generally, strings are *immutable*, you cannot assign to a specific letter in a string. You need to concatenate into a new string.

Comment: [`String.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) returns a new string, not a reference to a certain character of the original string. Your statement is the same as `'a' = 'a'.toUpperCase();`. `'a'` is a constant, it cannot be assigned a new value.

Comment: `TaLhaKhAn` or `TaLhAkHaN`? That would make more sense. There seems no reason why you had `ha` as consecutive lower-case letters in your example. I based my answer on what I think is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name.charAt(e)` calls a function which returns a value. You can't assign a value to a function call.

You can assign a value to a variable though. Simply build up a new string with the altered values. Your logic with `counter` also needed amending as in your version it would always be `false` after the first character.

Demo:

```js
var name = 'talhakhan';
var counter = true;
var newname = "";
for (var e = 0; e < name.length; e++) {
  if (counter) {
    newname += name.charAt(e).toUpperCase();
    counter = false;
  }
  else {
    newname += name.charAt(e).toLowerCase();
    counter = true;
  }
}

alert(newname);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Highly appreciated and learn something new today.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you want to produce `TaLhAkHaN` and not `TaLhaKhAn` judging by your code sample…

You can split the `string`, apply your transformation and join back into a `string`. (this will [break special characters made of surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-to-get-character-array-from-a-string/34717402#34717402))

```js
let name = 'talhakhan';
name = name.split('').map((character, i) =>
  (i % 2) ? character.toUpperCase() : character.toLowerCase()
).join('')
console.log(name)
```

Comment: Why not `(i % 2) ? character.toLowerCase() :  character.toUpperCase()`