# Do anyone understand this reduce method problem Im having?

Tags: javascript

Do anyone understand why `console.log(posArr)` is printing `[1,2,3]` and not `[0,1,2]`. Im trying to push to `nOfPos` all the index positions of my array :)

```js
function combinations(x) {
  let arr = x.toString().split('');
  console.log(arr)

  let nOfPos = [];
  let posArr = arr.map(x => nOfPos.push(arr.indexOf(arr[x])));
  let mult = posArr.reduce((acum, item) => acum * item);

  console.log(posArr);
  console.log(mult);
}

combinations(123)
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't ask about what we know. :)

Comment: Array.push returns the new length of the array, so posArr is an array of "new lengths".

Comment: i dont think arr.map(... push) is doing what you expect. .push will return the new length of the array, which is 1 indexed. not 0 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Did you mean `.indexOf(x)`?  I expect `x` is an element of `arr` , not an _index_ of an element in `arr`.  compare `.map((x, indexOfX) => ...)`

Comment: Why is this method called "combinations"?  Right now it looks like it's trying to compute the product of the indices of the first occurrence of each element in the array, which includes 0 because the first occurrence of the first element will always be at index 0, which means the answer will always be zero.  Surely that's not what you intended.  Or is it?  What are you doing?

Comment: `str.split('')` is a bad habit because it's not Unicode friendly.  `[...str]` is better.  [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-to-get-character-array-from-a-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to two errors in your code. Firstly `push()` returns the new length of the array, so that's why the mapped output contains the incremental `1,2,3...`.

Secondly, you need to search for `x` within `arr`, so you only need to pass `x`  to `indexOf()`.

With those issues corrected the code works:

```js
function combinations(x) {
  let arr = x.toString().split('');
  let posArr = arr.map(x => arr.indexOf(x));
  let mult = posArr.reduce((acum, item) => acum * item);

  console.log(posArr);
  console.log(mult);
}

combinations(123)
```

That being said, the purpose of `posArr` is a little redundant; it will always be an array of incremental values, up to the length of the string -1.

In addition, `mult` is redundant too as it will always be `0`, as you are multiplying by `0`.

Comment: A more concise version: `return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 'for in' loop to get the array indexes.

```
let posArr = [];
for (ix in arr) {
    posArr.push(ix)
}
```

Comment: That could be just `posArr = [...arr.keys()]`  But this is not the same as what would result from `.indexOf` if there are duplicates  e.g. `combinations (4455)`