# Problem with changing font of text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, output, svelte

So, i wanted to make a website to change the font of the text that you enter in, basically like lingojam.com.
I did make it but for some reason only some fonts are working and i have no idea why, can anyone help? sorry for the bad code, i am new to javascript, svelte, html etc

```js
function changeFont(text) {
  let output = "";

  for (const font in fonts) {
    const alphabet = Object.keys(fonts[font])[0];
    const transformedText = text
      .split("\n")
      .map((line) =>
        line
          .split("")
          .map((char) =>
            alphabet.includes(char)
              ? fonts[font][alphabet][alphabet.indexOf(char)]
              : char
          )
          .join("")
      )
      .join("\n");

    output += transformedText + "\n\n";
  }

  return output;
}

let newText = "Feliz, Navidad.";
let orignalText = "Feliz, Navidad.";

function changeInputText() {
  newText = changeFont(orignalText);
  console.log(newText);
}

changeInputText();
```

```html
<script>
let fonts = {
  1: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ",
  },
  2: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖᵠʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖᵠʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ",
  },
  3: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ",
  },
  4: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "",
  },
  5: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "",
  },
  6: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "",
  },
  7: {
    abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ:
      "",
  },
};
</script>
```

The output it gives is this:

```
ғᴇʟɪᴢ, ɴᴀᴠɪᴅᴀᴅ.
ᶠᵉˡᶦᶻ, ⁿᵃᵛᶦᵈᵃᵈ.
�, �.
�, �.
�, �.
�, �.
�, �.
```

As you can see, The first to lines are correct but other are weird and look corrupted.

Its self explanatory, i expected the converter to convert the text into different fonts correctly but instead only 2 fonts were correct and others were looking weird and corrupted.

Comment: Why are you not just changing the `font-family` _style_ of the elements you want to affect?

Comment: Remember to reduce your code to a [mcve]: you don't need to show all of them, only one that works, and one that doesn't. And you don't even need full words: just show it failing for one letter. And of course once you've done that, now you have something _you_ can investigate and you might not even need Stackoverflow anymore: why is that one letter already failing? (and on a programming note: no reason to use the key you're using, that can just be a separate, single const)

Comment: You're not changing *font*, you're changing *characters*.  If the goal is just to change fonts, it'll be a lot easier for you and a lot more stable for your user(s) if you use CSS to specify the font information.  Then the JavaScript code can simply change between different CSS classes.

Comment: Yes, as David says -- What you are doing is _not_ changing the font, you are changing the _character_ being used... from `a` 0x61 to (for example) `` 0xF0 0x9D 0x95 0x92 (utf8) or unicode U+1D552 "Mathematical Double-Struck Small A"

Comment: @StephenP While this may not be the best way to do it, it's still a reasonable question -- why aren't the replacements showing correctly? Similar code might be used for a simple cipher. It seems like the problem is that accessing characters from the replacement strings doesn't work as expected. Just printing `fonts[4]['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'][0]` produces garbage.

Comment: Agreed @Barmar - one application I thought of for it is making styled text (e.g. strikethrough or italic) to paste into places that don't otherwise support styling. I probably should have looked at lingojam first since OP mentioned it.

Comment: These characters are formed via multiple UTF-16 code units.  When you split, it's separating the 2 UTF-16 bits that form one character.   See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547609/how-can-i-get-a-character-array-from-a-string

Comment: i wanna change the characters, not the font family. because if i change the font family the user will try to copy it and get it in the default font

Comment: Thanks browser mator! its now working :)