# Loop for isn't getting the right position of the array, Why?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I came across the following situation:

My code:

```
alfabetoMadegues = "jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht"

var listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

dicionario_Madegues = {};

for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;) {
    listaLetras.forEach(element => {

        dicionario_Madegues[element] = i;
    })
};
```

If "j" is the first element of the array Why "j" is receiving 2 instead 0?. Why am i getting this result?

The expected result should be:

```
"j" 0
"n" 1
"g" 2
"m" 3
"c" 4
"l" 5
```

Comment: Can you please include the result you are getting?

Comment: You are running it through two loops, the `for` and the `forEach`. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: You should really first of all explain what your code is supposed to do, in your expectation, instead of letting people guess.

Comment: What does this suppose to do `for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;)` ? You are starting with `i === true` and then increment it

Comment: I'm basically want to get the value position of each element of the array listaLetras and set the result of the object dicionario_Madegues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Process each letter of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966476/javascript-process-each-letter-of-text)

Comment: A "i" is missing before "< listaLetras".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ES6 Soluce** *aka ECMA2015*  - [see compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

---

As second parameter of `Array.forEach` you can get the position of the element; as example :

```js
const alfabetoMadegues = 'jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht';

const listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

const dicionario_Madegues = {};

listaLetras.forEach((x, xi) => {
  dicionario_Madegues[x] = xi;
});

console.log(dicionario_Madegues);
```

---

Also, the use of `Array.reduce` is more appropriate; as example

**PS:** We use of Spread operator `...` and dynamic key naming `[x]`.

```js
const alfabetoMadegues = 'jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht';

const listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

const dicionario_Madegues = listaLetras.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => ({
  ...tmp,
  
  [x]: xi,
}), {});

console.log(dicionario_Madegues);
```

---

---

**ES5 Soluce**

---

```js
var alfabetoMadegues = 'jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht';

var listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

var dicionario_Madegues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < listaLetras.length; i += 1) {
  dicionario_Madegues[listaLetras[i]] = i;
}

console.log(dicionario_Madegues);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want that `forEach` inside the `for`. For the output you've described, you want to just remove that and replace it with `dicionario_Madegues[listaLetras[i]] = i;`.

You also have an error in your `for` loop. You have:

```
for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;) {
```

...which will run forever. The initialization and test should be separated with `;`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listaLetras.length; i++) {
// -----------^^^--------------------------^ (no `;` after `i++`)
```

Live example:

```js
var alfabetoMadegues = "jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht";

var listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

var dicionario_Madegues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < listaLetras.length; i++) {
    dicionario_Madegues[listaLetras[i]] = i;
}

console.log(dicionario_Madegues);
```

Also note the various places I've removed and added `;`. It's probably worth reviewing the rules for them.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping two times:

```
for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;) { // HERE
    listaLetras.forEach(element => { //HERE
        dicionario_Madegues[element] = i;
    })
};
```

So you have to use either the `for` or the `forEach`:

```js
alfabetoMadegues = "jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht"

var listaLetras = Array.from(alfabetoMadegues);

var dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOR = {};
var dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOREACH = {};

for (var i = 0 ; i < listaLetras.length ; i++ ) {
  dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOR[listaLetras[i]] = i;
};

listaLetras.forEach((letra, indice) => dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOREACH[letra] = indice);

console.log(dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOR);
console.log(dicionario_Madegues_CON_FOREACH);
```

There are also sintax errors in your `for`:

```
for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;)
```

That should be

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < listaLetras.length ; i++ )
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the provided answers you also can consider the following approach:

```js
alfabetoMadegues = "jngmclqskrzfvbwpxdht"

var obj = {}

alfabetoMadegues.split('').forEach((element, index) => obj[element] = index)

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on this line

```
for (var i = 0 < listaLetras.length; i++;) {
```

The `for` construct has three sections:

- Initilisation
- Condition
- Afterthought

Each section is separated with a ;

You've smooshed your condition `(i < listaLetras.length)` and initialisation together. The afterthought is being left blank.

The correct code would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < listaLetras.length; i++) {
```

The reason j is 2 is for two reasons;

On the first pass of the loop i is getting set the the value of `i < listaLetras.length` - this evaluates to true.

Next the loop runs the comparision (to check whether it should run the body of the loop). The comparision here is .... `i++` ! i is true so the comparison passes and then i is incremented.

i's value **true** is getting implicitly cast to a 1 for the increment.

When we hit the body of the loop it is now 2.

You are also looping two times with the foreach function - setting each value to i every iteration of i that occurs.